# Can the jQuery UI Datepicker be made to disable Saturdays and Sundays (and holidays)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I use a datepicker for choosing an appointment day.  I already set the date range to be only for the next month.  That works fine.  I want to exclude Saturdays and Sundays from the available choices.  Can this be done?  If so, how?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

There is the `beforeShowDay` option, which takes a function to be called for each date, returning true if the date is allowed or false if it is not.  From the docs:

---

**beforeShowDay**

The function takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with [0] equal to true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable and [1](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay) equal to a CSS class name(s) or '' for the default presentation. It is called for each day in the datepicker before is it displayed.

Display some national holidays in the datepicker.

```
$(".selector").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: nationalDays})   

natDays = [
  [1, 26, 'au'], [2, 6, 'nz'], [3, 17, 'ie'],
  [4, 27, 'za'], [5, 25, 'ar'], [6, 6, 'se'],
  [7, 4, 'us'], [8, 17, 'id'], [9, 7, 'br'],
  [10, 1, 'cn'], [11, 22, 'lb'], [12, 12, 'ke']
];

function nationalDays(date) {
    for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
      if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1
          && date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {
        return [false, natDays[i][2] + '_day'];
      }
    }
  return [true, ''];
}
```

One built in function exists, called noWeekends, that prevents the selection of weekend days.

```
$(".selector").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends })
```

---

To combine the two, you could do something like (assuming the `nationalDays` function from above):

```
$(".selector").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays})   

function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    if (noWeekend[0]) {
        return nationalDays(date);
    } else {
        return noWeekend;
    }
}
```

**Update**: Note that as of jQuery UI 1.8.19, the [beforeShowDay option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay) also accepts an optional third paremeter, a popup tooltip

Comment: Thanks for this, couldn't find this method in the docs anywhere.

Comment: excellent solution. particularly like how concise your explanation is. @Neil: http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/5851

Comment: With this i get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noWeekends' of undefined` the national days function works as expected though

Comment: If you have already instantiated it, you can update the option: **$('#selector'). datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', $.datepicker.noWeekends);**

Answer (score 43):

If you don't want the weekends to appear at all, simply:

CSS

```
th.ui-datepicker-week-end,
td.ui-datepicker-week-end {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: To hide the days completely but show the headers and blank spaces: `td.ui-datepicker-week-end {
     visibility: hidden;
 }`

Comment: This is a very neat way to exclude weekends.

Comment: Thanks, very nice :)

Comment: Thanks for this. I prefer the $.datepicker.noWeekends ...  but I had a datepicker in a jquery-ui Dialog window and couldn't get this to work without Jquery TypeError. There this CSS-Hiding was useful

Answer (score 32):

The datepicker has this functionality built in!

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-noWeekends

Answer (score 28):

These answers were very helpful. Thank you.

My contribution below adds an array where multiple days can return false (we're closed every Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday). And I bundled the specific dates plus years and the no-weekends functions.

If you want weekends off, add [Saturday], [Sunday] to the closedDays array.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: nonWorkingDates,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: '05/01/09',
        maxDate: '+2M',
        firstDay: 1
    });

    function nonWorkingDates(date){
        var day = date.getDay(), Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday = 3, Thursday = 4, Friday = 5, Saturday = 6;
        var closedDates = [[7, 29, 2009], [8, 25, 2010]];
        var closedDays = [[Monday], [Tuesday]];
        for (var i = 0; i < closedDays.length; i++) {
            if (day == closedDays[i][0]) {
                return [false];
            }

        }

        for (i = 0; i < closedDates.length; i++) {
            if (date.getMonth() == closedDates[i][0] - 1 &&
            date.getDate() == closedDates[i][1] &&
            date.getFullYear() == closedDates[i][2]) {
                return [false];
            }
        }

        return [true];
    }




});
```

Comment: You could just edit your old answer, instead of posting a brand new one - include both in the same answer, given how similar they are, or simply delete the old one and leave the better version

Answer (score 14):

The solution here that everyone likes seems to very intense... personally I think it's much easier to do something like this:

```
       var holidays = ["12/24/2012", "12/25/2012", "1/1/2013", 
            "5/27/2013", "7/4/2013", "9/2/2013", "11/28/2013", 
            "11/29/2013", "12/24/2013", "12/25/2013"];

       $( "#requestShipDate" ).datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function(date){
                show = true;
                if(date.getDay() == 0 || date.getDay() == 6){show = false;}//No Weekends
                for (var i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {
                    if (new Date(holidays[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {show = false;}//No Holidays
                }
                var display = [show,'',(show)?'':'No Weekends or Holidays'];//With Fancy hover tooltip!
                return display;
            }
        });
```

This way your dates are human readable.  It's not really that different it just makes more sense to me this way.

Answer (score 9):

You can use  noWeekends function to disable the weekend selection

```
  $(function() {
     $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
     beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
     });
     });
```

Answer (score 6):

This version of code will make u to get the holiday dates from the sql database and disable the specified date in the UI Datepicker

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  var holiDays = (function () {
    var val = null;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': 'getdate.php',
        'success': function (data) {
            val = data;
        }
    });
    return val;
    })();
  var natDays = holiDays.split('');

  function nationalDays(date) {
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    for (var i = 0; i ‘ natDays.length-1; i++) {
    var myDate = new Date(natDays[i]);
      if ((m == (myDate.getMonth())) && (d == (myDate.getDate())) && (y == (myDate.getFullYear())))
      {
        return [false];
      }
    }
    return [true];
  }

  function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
      if (noWeekend[0]) {
        return nationalDays(date);
      } else {
        return noWeekend;
    }
  }
  $(function() { 
    $("#shipdate").datepicker({
      minDate: 0,
      dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy',
      beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
      showOn: 'button',
      buttonImage: 'images/calendar.gif', 
      buttonImageOnly: true
     });
  });
});
```

Create a Database in sql and put you holiday dates in MM/DD/YYYY format as Varchar
Put the below contents in a file getdate.php

```
[php]
$sql="SELECT dates FROM holidaydates";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$chkdate = $_POST['chkdate'];
$str='';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$str .=$row[0].'';
}
echo $str;
[/php]
```

Happy Coding !!!! :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#selector").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: highlightDays });

...

var dates = [new Date("1/1/2011"), new Date("1/2/2011")];

function highlightDays(date) {

    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        if (date - dates[i] == 0) {
            return [true,'', 'TOOLTIP'];
        }
    }
    return [false];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this version, month, day, *and* year determines which days to block on the calendar.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  var d         = new Date();
  var natDays   = [[1,1,2009],[1,1,2010],[12,31,2010],[1,19,2009]];

  function nationalDays(date) {
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
      if ((m == natDays[i][0] - 1) && (d == natDays[i][1]) && (y == natDays[i][2]))
      {
        return [false];
      }
    }
    return [true];
  }
  function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
      if (noWeekend[0]) {
        return nationalDays(date);
      } else {
        return noWeekend;
    }
  }
  $(function() { 
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({

      minDate: new Date(d.getFullYear(), 1 - 1, 1),
      maxDate: new Date(d.getFullYear()+1, 11, 31),

      hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
      beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
     });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Bootstrap 3 version (bootstrap-datepicker.js) `beforeShowDay` expects a result in this format:

```
{ enabled: false, classes: "class-name", tooltip: "Holiday!" }
```

Alternatively, if you don't care about the CSS and tooltip then simply return a boolean `false` to make the date unselectable.

Also, there is no `$.datepicker.noWeekends`, so you need to do something along the lines of this:

```
var HOLIDAYS = {  // Ontario, Canada holidays
    2017: {
        1: { 1: "New Year's Day"},
        2: { 20: "Family Day" },
        4: { 17: "Easter Monday" },
        5: { 22: "Victoria Day" },
        7: { 1: "Canada Day" },
        8: { 7: "Civic Holiday" },
        9: { 4: "Labour Day" },
        10: { 9: "Thanksgiving" },
        12: { 25: "Christmas", 26: "Boxing Day"}
    }
};

function filterNonWorkingDays(date) {
    // Is it a weekend?
    if ([ 0, 6 ].indexOf(date.getDay()) >= 0)
        return { enabled: false, classes: "weekend" };
    // Is it a holiday?
    var h = HOLIDAYS;
    $.each(
        [ date.getYear() + 1900, date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDate() ], 
        function (i, x) {
            h = h[x];
            if (typeof h === "undefined")
                return false;
        }
    );
    if (h)
        return { enabled: false, classes: "holiday", tooltip: h };
    // It's a regular work day.
    return { enabled: true };
}

$("#datePicker").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: filterNonWorkingDays });
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
     beforeShowDay: function( date ) {
                        var day = date.getDay();
                        return [ ( day > 0 && day < 6 ), "" ];
                    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

For Saturday and  Sunday You can do something like this

```
             $('#orderdate').datepicker({
                               daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]
                 });
```

Comment: This is not for JqueryUI Datepicker

Answer (score -1):

To Disable the Weekends the API has a built-in feature

```
$('#data_1 .input-group.date').datepicker({
   daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6],
 });
```

0 = Sunday

6 = Sunday