# jQuery UI Datepicker - Disable specific days

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Is there any (easy) way to set the jQuery UI Datepicker to disallow selection of specific, predetermined days?

I was able to get [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holida/503082#503082) working, however, it produces a null error which prevents it from displaying in IE.

> 'natDays[...].0' is null or not an object

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** Might help if I included some code, right? Anyway, most of this was taken straight from the aforementioned thread:

```
natDays = [
        [7, 23], [7, 24], [8, 13], [8, 14], 
    ];

    function nationalDays(date) {
        for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
            if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1
            && date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {
                return [false, natDays[i][2] + '_day'];
            }
        }
        return [true, ''];
    }

    function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
        var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
        if (noWeekend[0]) {
            return nationalDays(date);
        } else {
            return noWeekend;
        }
    }


    $(function() { 
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            inline: true,
            minDate: new Date(2009, 6, 6), 
            maxDate: new Date(2009, 7, 14), 
            numberOfMonths: 2, 
            hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
            altField: '#alternate',
        }); 
    });
```

Thanks again!

Comment: could you paste your code of what you have thats producing the error

Comment: Need a code sample of at least the line in question...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried declaring natDays properly with the 'var' keyword in front?

Also - you have an extra comma at the end of your natDays definition.

natDays[i][2] won't work as your the arrays only have 2 items in them - try just ''

Additionally, you'll want to set your beforeShowDay function name correctly - doesn't look like it's even calling your custom function

Comment: Hmm... just tried it. No luck. This is the error that IE is returning:

'natDays[...].0' is null or not an object

Comment: See my recent edit... it's not defined properly (extra comma)

Comment: Okay... I think we're getting somewhere! The extra comma fixed things in IE8. Can you show me what you mean with your second comment though? (I'm a JS novice... can you tell?) Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

Here is a way to disable specific dates from being selected:

```
var unavailableDates = ["9-5-2011","14-5-2011","15-5-2011"];

function unavailable(date) {
  dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) < 0) {
    return [true,"","Book Now"];
  } else {
    return [false,"","Booked Out"];
  }
}

$('#iDate').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: unavailable });
```

[*Source: jQuery - Datepicker - Disable Specific Dates*](http://tokenposts.blogspot.com/2011/05/jquery-datepicker-disable-specific.html)

Comment: Just a note - this is the D-M-Y format of date.  To use M-D-Y, change dmy to 

(date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getDate() + "-" + date.getFullYear();

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `beforeShowDay` option. I needed to disable any day past the 28th of the month. Here is my code.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDate();
        if (day > 28) {
            return [false];
        } else {
            return [true];
        }
    }
});
```

Here is more information about it: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

The date variable passed into the beforeShowDay callback is a JavaScript date object, so it can be formatted using various libraries, a timestamp can be retrieved using date.getTime(), etc.

Comment: @WHK I'm sorry but I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
```

will be

```
beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with IE is most probably on the following line:

```
altField: '#alternate',
});
```

Try to remove the comma symbol and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var unavailableDates = ["19-8-2014","14-9-2014"];

 function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" +date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) < 0) {
     return [true,"","Book Now"];
    } else {
  return [false,"","Booked Out"];
  }
 }

 $('#iDate').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: unavailable });
```

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vfod0krm/

Comment: just to note, this will show "book now" as tooltip for dates that have been disabled using the minDate/maxDate options