# jQueryUI Datepicker noWeekendsAndHolidaysAndWeekDay

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've got this answer working but I'd like to extend it:
[jQuery UI Datepicker - Disable specific days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677976/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-specific-days)

I'm stuck on adding this method to the solution:

```
beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 5)];
    }
```

to noWeekendsAndHolidays. How can I add that in?

So, the datepicker **beforeShowDay** option would have 3 "false" returns:

1. no weekends
2. no holidays
3. no selected weekday ("we're closed on Fridays,
   too")

working code with the first two options (I need help with the third):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    noWeekends: true,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
    minDate: '-1M -1W -1D',
    maxDate: '+1M',
    firstDay: 1
});


function nationalDays(date){
    var natDays = [[7, 26, 'Shop-Closed']];
    for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
        if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1 &&
            date.getDate() == natDays[i][1] ) {
                return [false, natDays[i][2] + '_day'];
            }
    }
    return [true, ''];
}

function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date){
    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    if (noWeekend[0]) {
        return nationalDays(date);  
    }
    else {
        return noWeekend;
    }
}    
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date){
    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    if (noWeekend[0]) {
        var isNotFriday = noFridays(date);
        if (isNotFriday[0]) {
            return nationalDays(date);
        }
        else {
            return isNotFriday;
        }
    }
    else {
        return noWeekend;
    }
}

function noFridays(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 5),""];
}
```