# Disable Week Days on DatePicker Calendar with jQueryUI

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am working with the datepicker from jQuery-UI and I was wondering if there was anyway to disable/modify the calendar for it to only display month and year and only that.

I tried the answer here [jQuery UI Datepicker - Disable specific days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677976/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-specific-days), but it did not quite do what I wanted. It was not really working and the I wanted to disable specific datepicker not all of them.

Can someone help at all with this?

Thanks in advance.

**PS:** so far my code looks like this:

```
$(".crud_date_picker_month").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm'
});
```

jQuery UI version 1.8.21

The can see code here: http://jsfiddle.net/VJADH/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bopperben/DBpJe/

Comment: What's the point of using the datepicker then? Just use two selects.

Comment: Your submission title suggests one thing and the text asks for another. Make up your mind.

Comment: And another thing, you code shows the `datetimepicker` which isn't a jQuery UI widget.

Comment: anyway, the question is duplicated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only

Comment: @Yankov: thank you did not realise this, just a typo

Comment: @loops: it isn't please re-read the post, what was on the other question was not quite what I was looking for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if there was anyway to disable/modify the calendar for
>   it to only display month and year and only that.

To only display month and year using CSS:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar{
    display:none;    
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ANF2y/) - Only show Month/Year using CSS

---

If you need to do it programmatically you can add the following code:

```
$(".date-picker").focus(function () {
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tdjUn/) - Only show Month/Year programmatically

---

Comment: issue is if I do that it will remove it for all my other calendar and I just want to do it on one or two and I possibly have 5 or more of them)...

Comment: @AKFourSeven: You can do it programmatically as well. I added that version too now. Either-way if you want to target a specific date picker, you can either programmatically do it when you open the data-pickers you are interested in or give each date-picker an `id` and add that to the CSS or programmatic solution, similar to: `$("#myDatePicker .ui-datepicker-calendar")` or `#myDatePicker .ui-datepicker-calendar{ display:none;}` There is many ways of doing it.

Comment: thanks just thought about it as well, this was quite on point, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To disable the month and year (as per your submission title!!), hide the header:

```
.ui-datepicker-header {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VJADH/1/