# How to count "+1" when a specific date occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have this code through which I show a future working day, thus excluding weekends. I would also like to exclude personalized holiday dates, in which case the same thing happens (count ++, I guess).

For example, I would like to exclude these dates: `["2019-11-6", "2019-11-13"]`
How can I integrate this into the code?

I need this to show a future delivery date on a business day, excluding weekends and some custom dates.

I've read and tested countless similar questions here on StackOverflow, but I haven't found anything that works.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var monthNames = ["gennaio", "febbraio", "marzo", "aprile", "maggio", "giugno", "luglio", "agosto", "settembre", "ottobre", "novembre", "dicembre"];
  var dayNames = ["domenica", "lunedì", "martedì", "mercoledì", "giovedì", "venerdì", "sabato"]

  var endDate = "",
    noOfDaysToAdd = 1,
    count = 0;
  var someDate = new Date();
  var numberOfDaysToAdd = noOfDaysToAdd;
  someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate());

  while (count < noOfDaysToAdd) {
    endDate = new Date(someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + 1));
    if (endDate.getDay() != 0 && endDate.getDay() != 6) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  $('#Date').html(dayNames[endDate.getDay()] + ' ' + endDate.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[endDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + endDate.getFullYear());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Date"></div>
```

The code works well for the exclusion of weekends, but I would like help to add customized holiday dates as well.

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22065143/how-do-i-disable-public-holidays-in-a-jquery-ui-date-picker

Comment: Thanks for immediate support, Rory McCrossan!
Unfortunately though, although I did a lot of research and attempts, I couldn't integrate the code in the question you suggested with mine.
Perhaps because that refers to a datepicker, or because of my incompetence :)
Any other suggestions or practical examples? Thank you very much.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip Silentw! Unfortunately I have already tried with Moment.js, but it is a bit too complicated for me, also because I would need only this function above in the whole site. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Silentw for giving me the right direction!
After several researches I realized that what was missing was just setting the numbers of the dates separated by commas. Now it seems to work perfectly. Thank you all for the support.

**Here is the working code for those interested:**

---

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var monthNames = ["gennaio", "febbraio", "marzo", "aprile", "maggio", "giugno", "luglio", "agosto", "settembre", "ottobre", "novembre", "dicembre"];
  var dayNames = ["domenica", "lunedì", "martedì", "mercoledì", "giovedì", "venerdì", "sabato"];
  var holidays = ["2019, 11, 8", "2019, 11, 11", "2019, 11, 12", "2019, 11, 13", "2019, 11, 14", "2019, 11, 15", "2019, 11, 18"];
  var endDate = "",
    noOfDaysToAdd = 3,
    count = 0;
  var someDate = new Date(new Date().toDateString());
  var numberOfDaysToAdd = noOfDaysToAdd;
  someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate());
  while (count < noOfDaysToAdd) {
    endDate = new Date(someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + 1));
    var isHoliday = holidays.find(holiday => endDate.getTime() == new Date(holiday).getTime());
    if (isHoliday) {
      console.log('holiday, skipping');
    } else if (endDate.getDay() != 0 && endDate.getDay() != 6) {
      count++;
    }
  }
$('#Date').html(dayNames[endDate.getDay()] + ' ' + endDate.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[endDate.getMonth()]);   
});
```

---

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Date"></div>
```

<sub>*Added on behalf of OP*</sub>