# Disable national holidays present in my database using jquery pickadate plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker, pickadate

Hi I am working on rails4 project and I want to disable all national holidays and weekend dates in my pickadate. Or I have to use [pickdate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) I am not getting how to do this.
I have done the following for disabling the weekends.

```
 $( '.new_leave_datepicker' ).pickadate({
        selectMonths: true,
        selectYears: 25,
        disable: [
            1,7
        ],
        min: Date.now()
    });
```

Its working fine for this but how to do for national holidays that am not getting. I am having table holidays in which I have holidaydates.
 Please guide what steps I have to follow for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your code? Did you try anything before asking the question?

Comment: duplicate of I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677976/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-specific-days

Comment: this is duplicate question. I have already given you a link which has the correct answer

Comment: @dinshawraje : Do you have national holidays dates list in database?

Comment: yes I have holiday list in my database

Comment: @dinshawraje : Is there a model to fetch that list? Could you add that also on your post, please?

Comment: @dinshawraje : http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/#method-set-disable-enable please check this link.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable sets of dates by the following methods:

```
   picker.set('disable', [

      // Using a collection of arrays formatted as [YEAR,MONTH,DATE]
      [2016,9,3], [2016,9,9], [2016,9,20],

      // Using JavaScript Date objects
      new Date(2015,9,13), new Date(2015,9,24)
    ])
```

Please refer this link
http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/#method-set-disable-enable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holid/503082#503082  for more details please refer this link

Comment: May I ask why it's got the down vote?
Have you checked this link?

Comment: I am not the one who down voted your answer. While I can tell "WHY?", READ the question carefully and then see your answer. You'll know WHY.

Comment: @dinshawraje :  I updated my answer please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array of disabled dates like this:

```
var datesToDisable = [ 1, 4, 7, [2015,3,8], [2015,3,19], new Date(2015,3,26) ]


$( '.new_leave_datepicker' ).pickadate({
    selectMonths: true,
    selectYears: 25,
    disable: datesToDisable,
    min: Date.now()
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `jquery-ui` [datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/). There is a method named **noWeekends**.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
   beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});
```

But there is no documentation for National holidays. You have to customize the datepicker options.

Comment: may I ask why it's got the down vote? It might help me to find my mistakes.

Comment: I am not the one who down voted your answer. While I can tell "WHY?", READ the question carefully and then see your answer. You'll know WHY.