# jQuery Datepicker - Multiple instances and disable previously selected dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where the user can select three different appointment days using the jQuery UI Datepicker. When the user selects a day in the first field, I would like that date blocked out from the other two fields. I currently am also disabling Sundays, but cannot get dynamic date disabling working.

```
    Appointment Time 1<br />
<input id="appointment1_date" type="text" name="appointment1_date" value="Select..." />

Appointment Time 2<br />
<input id="appointment2_date" type="text" name="appointment2_date" value="Select..." />

Appointment Time 3<br />
<input id="appointment3_date" type="text" name="appointment3_date" value="Select..." />


        <script type="text/javascript">
        function noSunday(date){
          var day = date.getDay();
                      return [(day > 0), ''];
          };
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#appointment1_date").datepicker(
            {
                minDate: +2, 
                beforeShowDay: noSunday
            });
        });
        $(function() {
            $("#appointment2_date").datepicker(
            {
                minDate: +2, 
                beforeShowDay: noSunday
            });
        });
        $(function() {
            $("#appointment3_date").datepicker(
            {
                minDate: +2, 
                beforeShowDay: noSunday
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To block out dates from the other fields, you have to obtain the date and do the comparison in your handling function.  Given the code you provided, the following should work as a replacement for `noSunday`:

```
function noSunday(date) {
      var day = date.getDay();
      return [
          (day > 0 &&
           date.valueOf() != $('#appointment1_date').datepicker('getDate').valueOf()
          ),
          ''
      ];
};
```

Basically, not only do you want to make sure that `day > 0` so that it isn't a Sunday, but also make sure that the date is not equal to the date given by `appointment1_date`.  Using `.datepicker('getDate')` and comparing its `valueOf()` with `date` is the key.

You might want to rename it something like `noSundayOrSelected` or something equally descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the beforeShowDay function to set disabled dates.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holida) for a full explanation.

Comment: Yes, I'm using that to block out holidays, but cannot seem to add a dynamic date from an existing field to the array.