# how to disable previously selected dates in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have written code in jsfiddle.net/udgeet/VUb5r/

I have to disable the previously selected date

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116778/jquery-datepicker-multiple-instances-and-disable-previously-selected-dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use datePicker's [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) option to specify which dates you want to enable or disable.

Then it's just a case of writing a functions to

a) get the dates from the select into an array:

```
function daysToDisable() {
    var dates = [];
    for (i = 0; i < $('#inputdates option').length; i++) {
        dates[i] = new Date($('#inputdates option').eq(i).val()).toString();
    }
    return dates;
}
```

and b) return true or false if the current date is in the array

```
function disableDates(date) {
    var days = daysToDisable();
    for (i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {  
        if ($.inArray(date.toString(), days) != -1) {
            return [false];
        }  
    }
    return [true];  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vy562/1/