# How can I use Jquery Datepicker to highlight with befereshowday two different kind of special dates?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, days

I mean, I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holida/1532667#1532667) a way to disable an array of nationalDays.

I'm trying to make a code to disable the national days and also to highlight some other days (I'm coding a web app and I will pass another array of days) but to let them enabled.

Imagine a calendar where you can see three different day colors. The first one, today's date. The second, greyed disabled national days. And in a third color, different days where something special will happen.

Is this possible.

Also, where can i find the css codes in datepicker ui to change the default date, and the disabled date css properties.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the function from the page you linked to:

```
$(".selector").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: specialAndNationalDays});

natDays = [
  [1, 26, 'au'], [2, 6, 'nz'], [3, 17, 'ie'],
  [4, 27, 'za'], [5, 25, 'ar'], [6, 6, 'se'],
  [7, 4, 'us'], [8, 17, 'id'], [9, 7, 'br'],
  [10, 1, 'cn'], [11, 22, 'lb'], [12, 12, 'ke']
];
speDays = [
  [1, 10, 'mbd'], // Moms Bday
  [7, 20, 'dbd']  // Dads Bday
];

function nationalDays(date) {
    for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
      if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1
          && date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {
        return [false, natDays[i][2] + '_day'];
      }
    }
  return [true, ''];
}
function specialAndNationalDays(date) {
    for (i = 0; i < speDays.length; i++) {
      if (date.getMonth() == speDays[i][0] - 1
          && date.getDate() == speDays[i][1]) {
        return [true, speDays[i][2] + '_day']; 
        // first variable in return enables(true)/disables(false) the date
      }
    }
  return nationalDays(date);
}
```

Comment: I think something is not working right. The second function (specialAndNationalDays) is calling the first one (nationalDays) and the National Days are being disabled OK. But nothing is happening with the other special days.

I tried changing true/false in the return line of the special days function but it doesn't seems to work. I will try to find why not and post it if I find the answer. Thanks!!

Comment: Jojo... I'm sorry, IT WORKS!! I forgot to change the name of the function inside my calendar parameters. Thanks a lot!!