# How to Highlight specific dates in the datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

How to Highlight in `BOLD` specific dates in the datepicker? I have the array with dates `var datesArray = new Array();` I know that I need to use `beforeShowDay:` method, but I can't figure it out to make it work.

This is my function:

```
            $(function() {
                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
                    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {                             
                        dateSelected(dateText, tid) // run my function on click
                    }                     
                });
            });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use Jquery Datepicker to highlight with befereshowday two different kind of special dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534172/how-can-i-use-jquery-datepicker-to-highlight-with-befereshowday-two-different-ki)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to use beforeShowDay event, [here is the test](http://jsfiddle.net/RjKw6/)

```
   ...
   beforeShowDay: function(d_date){
        console.log(d_date);
        //Here compare your Date Array and the d_date
        var d_picker = new Date(d_date);
        var s_class_highligth = '';
        if($.inArray(d_picker.getDate(),a_date_array)>-1){
            s_class_highligth = 'my_cell_highligth';
        }

        return [true, s_class_highligth, 'this is optional tooltip'];
    }
    ...
```