# Highlight Specific Dates in Bootstrap Datepicker with Variable Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I know how to add a class to a date using `beforeShowDay`.

How can I use a specific color for a day, instead of assigning a css class for that day?

Similar Questions:

[How to Highlight specific dates in the datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052615/how-to-highlight-specific-dates-in-the-datepicker)

[Add class to a multiple/specific day in bootstrap datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604026/add-class-to-a-multiple-specific-day-in-bootstrap-datepicker)

Comment: where is your code? please see how to ask question.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the library.. add a new variable highlight in the option. then if the option is present highlight by using data attribute selector

```
$( "td[data-day='08/23/2016']" ).css('background','blue');
```