# Disable specific dates in jquery

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, picker

I am using the jquery date picker found here: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerStartEnd.html that allows the user to pick a start and end date.

However I want to be able to disable specific dates.

I tried to implement the code found here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holida) that discusses disabling national holidays.

Here is my complete code:

```
$(function()
{


 $('.date-pick').datePicker({ beforeShowDay: nationalDays})
// $(".selector").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: nationalDays})   

 var natDays = [
   [1, 26, 'au'], [2, 6, 'nz'], [3, 17, 'ie'],
   [4, 27, 'za'], [5, 25, 'ar'], [6, 6, 'se'],
   [7, 4, 'us'], [8, 17, 'id'], [9, 7, 'br'],
   [10, 1, 'cn'], [11, 22, 'lb'], [12, 12, 'ke']
 ];

 function nationalDays(date) {
  for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
    if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1
     && date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {
   return [false, natDays[i][2] + '_day'];
    }
  }
   return [true, ''];
 }

 $('#start-date').bind(
  'dpClosed',
  function(e, selectedDates)
  {
   var d = selectedDates[0];
   if (d) {
    d = new Date(d);
    $('#end-date').dpSetStartDate(d.addDays(1).asString());
   }
  }
 );
 $('#end-date').bind(
  'dpClosed',
  function(e, selectedDates)
  {
   var d = selectedDates[0];
   if (d) {
    d = new Date(d);
    $('#start-date').dpSetEndDate(d.addDays(-1).asString());
   }
  }
 );

});
```

But this does not seem to work.

I would really appreciate any assistance with solving this!

Comment: You might want to furnish more info on the behavior/error you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

The [Simple Calendar Widget](http://www.garrett.nildram.co.uk/calendar/scw.htm#examples-demo) has that sort of capability built-in.  Could you switch?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused between two different date pickers. The link you show referring to "beforeShowDay" is documentation for the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) datepicker widget. But it appears you are using [my date picker widget](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/).

With my widget you need to use a `renderCallback` to allow you to disable certain dates. These two examples show how:

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerCustomCellRender.html
(a popup calendar with weekends disabled)

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/renderCalendarBankHolidays.html (another example showing `renderCalendar` with a `renderCallback` which shows UK bank holidays - `datePicker` uses `renderCalendar` behind the scenes so you can pass the `renderCallback` in in the same manner.

Comment: p.s. just noticed the date on this question. No idea why it suddenly turned up on my RSS feed for questions tagged jquery and datepicker but I guess you've maybe already found a solution!