# Jquery UI datepicker. Disable array of Dates

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have been trying to search for a solution to my Jquery ui datepicker problem and I'm having no luck. Here's what I'm trying to do...

I have an application where i'm doing some complex PHP to return a JSON array of dates that I want BLOCKED out of the Jquery UI Datepicker. I am returning this array:

```
["2013-03-14","2013-03-15","2013-03-16"]
```

Is there not a simple way to simply say: block these dates from the datepicker?

I've read the UI documentation and I see nothing that helps me. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: [Disable specific dates in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584794/disable-specific-dates-in-jquery)

Comment: [jquery-ui datepicker disable specific days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677976/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-specific-days)

Comment: [Can the jquery-ui datepicker be made to disable saturdays, sundays and holidays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holidays)

Comment: [Datepicker for web page that can allow only specific dates to be clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890418/datepicker-for-web-page-that-can-allow-only-specific-dates-to-be-clicked/1962849)

Comment: Can someone signpost me to similar questions but using Materialize datepicker?

Answer (score 224, accepted):

You can use [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) to do this

The following example disables dates 14 March 2013 thru 16 March 2013

```
var dates = ['2013-03-14', '2013-03-15', '2013-03-16'];

$('input').datepicker
({
    beforeShowDay: function(date)
    {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [dates.indexOf(string) == -1];
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CxNNh/1/)

Comment: I KIND OF see where you're going with that. How would I incorporate my array of dates though.

Comment: WOW. You're a freaking genius bro. I don't know why this isn't already in the stack overflow posts for this question since its been asked a million times. All the examples posted above are too complicated, this is nice and simple. 5 stars. Thanks.

Comment: i have downloaded the code 
http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.10.3&components=1000000000001000000000000000000000
but when i am integrating the above code in it 
its not working  pls help

Comment: One upvote is not enough.  Some people make things way more complicated than they need to be.  Thank you so much for a simple, working snippet.  Very useful.

Comment: Additional notes: using Date objects in the array would not work; for some reason, two Date objects with the same value are not matched when using indexOf (or jQuery.inArray for old browsers compat).  Also months in Date objects are 0-based instead of 1-based, which is one more thing to look out for in your backend or template code.

Comment: If you also want do exclude weekends besides these custom dates, replace the return line by this: `return array.indexOf(string) != -1 ? [false] : $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);`

Comment: Why can't I fav this?

Comment: Hi, how can I gray out weekends(Saturdays and Sundays) along with specific dates?

Answer (score 20):

IE 8 doesn't have indexOf function, so I used jQuery inArray instead.

```
$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [$.inArray(string, array) == -1];
    }
});
```

Comment: @ChristopherStrydom you'd be surprised how many people still use it.

Comment: This is because IE8 is the newest IE browser which will run on WinXP (SP3).

Comment: It does however support the indexOf() function on a string for finding the position of a substring in that string.

Answer (score 12):

If you also want to block Sundays (or other days) as well as the array of dates, I use this code:

```
jQuery(function($){

    var disabledDays = [
       "27-4-2016", "25-12-2016", "26-12-2016",
       "4-4-2017", "5-4-2017", "6-4-2017", "6-4-2016", "7-4-2017", "8-4-2017", "9-4-2017"
    ];

   //replace these with the id's of your datepickers
   $("#id-of-first-datepicker,#id-of-second-datepicker").datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: function(date){
         var day = date.getDay();
         var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('d-m-yy', date);
         var isDisabled = ($.inArray(string, disabledDays) != -1);

         //day != 0 disables all Sundays
         return [day != 0 && !isDisabled];
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').datepicker({
   beforeShowDay: function(date){
       var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
       return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**beforeShowDate** didn't work for me, so I went ahead and developed my own solution:

```
$('#embeded_calendar').datepicker({
               minDate: date,
                localToday:datePlusOne,
               changeDate: true,
               changeMonth: true,
               changeYear: true,
               yearRange: "-120:+1",
               onSelect: function(selectedDateFormatted){

                     var selectedDate = $("#embeded_calendar").datepicker('getDate');

                    deactivateDates(selectedDate);
                   }

           });


              var excludedDates = [ "10-20-2017","10-21-2016", "11-21-2016"];

              deactivateDates(new Date());

            function deactivateDates(selectedDate){
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                      var thisMonthExcludedDates = thisMonthDates(selectedDate);
                      thisMonthExcludedDates = getDaysfromDate(thisMonthExcludedDates);
                       var excludedTDs = page.find('td[data-handler="selectDay"]').filter(function(){
                           return $.inArray( $(this).text(), thisMonthExcludedDates) >= 0
                       });

                       excludedTDs.unbind('click').addClass('ui-datepicker-unselectable');
                   }, 10);
            }

            function thisMonthDates(date){
              return $.grep( excludedDates, function( n){
                var dateParts = n.split("-");
                return dateParts[0] == date.getMonth() + 1  && dateParts[2] == date.getYear() + 1900;
            });
            }

            function getDaysfromDate(datesArray){
                  return  $.map( datesArray, function( n){
                    return n.split("-")[1]; 
                });
             }
```

Comment: Can we do this same thing on dateRangePicker??

Answer (score 1):

For DD-MM-YY use this code:

var array = ["03-03-2017', '03-10-2017', '03-25-2017"]

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
    return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});

function highlightDays(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    if (new Date(dates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
        return [true, 'highlight'];
    }
}
return [true, ''];
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for daterangepicker, I want to disabled an array of dates on date-range-picker??

Comment: Can you please define your question?

Comment: I have date range picker suppose: 01/01/2017 - 31/03/2017. I want to highlighted some dates an array of custom dates dates between this range. on date-range calendar. 
$dates = ['02/01/2017','03/01/2017'...till] these dates. is is possible?

Comment: like in datepicker we can use :beforeShowDay function for this purpose, what is there in date-range-picker:
http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable particular date(s) in jquery datepicker then here is the simple demo for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arrDisabledDates = {};
    arrDisabledDates[new Date("08/28/2017")] = new Date("08/28/2017");
    arrDisabledDates[new Date("12/23/2017")] = new Date("12/23/2017");
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var day = date.getDay(),
                    bDisable = arrDisabledDates[date];
            if (bDisable)
                return [false, "", ""]
        }
    });
</script>
```