# How to disable dates on calendar using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
$(".datepicker-to").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: "0D"
});
```

Then my textboxes are:

```
<div>
    <span>Date From :</span>
    <input type="text" class="datepicker-to" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" />
</div>
<div>
    <span>Date To :</span>
    <input type="text" class="datepicker-to" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" />
</div>
```

Now, when I clicked a date in "from" txtbox I want to disable the dates in "to" txtbox. The dates that needs to be disble are dates before the dates I entered in the "from" txtbox because obviously it is not valid to enter dates from jan21-jan9...I hope I make myself clear...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery UI datepicker. Disable array of Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates)

Answer (score 1):

In `datepicker` select callback you can put the `textbox` attribute `readonly`.So it goes in to inactive mode.

```
 $(".datepicker-to").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
        maxDate: "0D",
       onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
         //disable another one here            
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Baadsha wrote, use `onSelect` to find out when the date was picked. 
However I suggest that you then set the `minDate` (using the *after initilization* method) and `refresh` the widget.

```
$("#dateFrom").datepicker({
    "onSelect": function () {
        var input = $(this);
        $("#dateTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", input.datepicker("getDate"));
        $("#dateTo").datepicker("refresh");
    }
});
$("#dateTo").datepicker();
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uZvKd/1/)

To have the datepickers update in both directions set the `maxDate` too:

```
$("#dateTo").datepicker({
    "onSelect": function () {
        var input = $(this);
        $("#dateFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", input.datepicker("getDate"));
        $("#dateFrom").datepicker("refresh");
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/uZvKd/2/)

---

**UPDATE:**
To disable the selected date, too, you will have to compensate and offset the selected date by one day:

```
var dayAfter = input.datepicker("getDate");
dayAfter.setDate(dayAfter.getDate() + 1);
$("#dateTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dayAfter);
```

[FIDDLE DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/uZvKd/3/)

Comment: please refer to my new post...I want my selected date in "from" to be disbled in my "To"