# jQuery UI datepicker setDate < minDate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to `setDate` to let's say June 2013 but have the `minDate` defined to August 2013? I'm trying to do that and it doesn't work for some reason. The expected behavior is to see the datepicker with the correct month (June) and all dates should be disabled (since the mindate is August).

Example code (http://jsfiddle.net/npBz3/):

```
$('#dp').datepicker();
$('#dp').datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );
$('#dp').datepicker("option", "minDate", "10/12/2013" );
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use minDate in this example as you cannot view any dates before that. You would need to disable all the dates from your set date, to your chosen minimum date. You might find this useful [Jquery UI datepicker. Disable array of Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates)

Answer (score 0):

Is it this you are looking for

> [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/npBz3/1/)

```
$('#dp').datepicker({
  changeMonth: false,
  changeYear: false,
  stepMonths: 0
});
$('#dp').datepicker("option", "minDate", "-1" );
$('#dp').datepicker("option", "maxDate", "6/31/2013" );
```

Comment: This doesn't work, if I add ``$('#dp').datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );`` I will still see July 2013 on the calendar as the month and not October 2012

Comment: @hoverhand, dude, according to my understanding i coded, it may be that i have understood the requirement wrong, can you please explain in other words what  your expected output.

Comment: I'm trying to basically show the month that I'm setting on 'setDate' when I'm setting the minDate to be prior to that. So for example I want to set the date to July 2013 and have the mindate set to May 2013. What I expect to see is the month July with all the dates disabled, that doesn't happen and what I see is the month May in the calendar instead.\