# enable disable dates in jquery calendar on change event

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am stuck in JQuery Calendar

i have a drop down who have list of cities

```
<select name="flyto_code" id="flyto_code">
    <option value="ISB">Islamabad (ISB)</option>
    <option value="KHI">Karachi (KHI)</option>
</select>
```

and i have dynamic (came from ajax) array filled with the dates like..

```
var availableDatesForKhi = ["12-10-2013","13-10-2013","14-10-2013","15-10-2013","16-10-2013","17-10-2013","18-10-2013"];
var availableDatesForIsb = ["12-11-2013","13-10-2013","14-11-2013","15-10-2013","16-11-2013","17-10-2013","18-11-2013"];
```

when i select KHI from dropbox DatePicker should enable availableDatesForKhi

```
$( "#departure_date" ).datepicker({
beforeShowDay: available,
numberOfMonths:1,
showWeek: true,
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
showAnim: "slideDown",
onClose: function( selectedDate )
{
$( "#return_date" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
}
});


    function available(date)
    {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if($.inArray(dmy, availableDatesForKhi ) != -1)
    {
    return [true, "","Available"];
    } 
    else 
    {
    return [false,"","unAvailable"];
    }
    }
```

how do i call & create a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates) to constrain the dates and at [jQuery UI API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) for the beforeShowDay method.

Comment: thanks, in a simple way it's working and i tried but in my scenario date will come dynamically via ajax

Comment: @HeartDisk So if the value of your dropdown changes call a function which loads the array of dates into a local array which is referenced in the beforeShowDay method. This is what I whould do.