# Disable Christmas Day on J-Query Date Picker

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

I don't know much about J-Query but I am using a J-Query UI-date picker in a program I am creating. My program allows you to book off holidays in the company but I want to disable every Christmas Day on the calendar and every New Years day as the employees will already have this date off. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates

Comment: I want to disable every Christmas and new year, not just dates that are in an array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable all Christmas days / new years days, you could do something like this:

```
function IsChristmas(date) {
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    return (day === 25 && month === 12);
}

function IsNewYearsDay(date) {
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    return (day === 1 && month === 1);
}

$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        return [(!IsChristmas(date) && !IsNewYearsDay(date))];
    }
});
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RDDdT/1/) for a demo.

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I have also used this and it works fine, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Haydn_JW - You're welcome. Glad it was useful to you.