# Customize specific disabled dates within a range using jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jQuery UI datepicker for a form where users request a tour of the school. There is a date range that the tours are being held, and within that range the site admin may disable certain days that are booked. No problem so far:

```
/* array of booked dates generated from CMS backend */
var disabledDates = [
    '2015-05-06',
    '2015-05-08' // examples
];

$('[name="date_of_visit"]').datepicker({
    minDate: '4/30/2015', // Range start
    maxDate: '10/1/2015', // Range end
    beforeShowDay: function(date) { // Disable custom dates
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [$.inArray(string, disabledDates) == -1];
    }
});
```

I got the `beforeShowDay` code from this post: [Jquery UI datepicker. Disable array of Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15400775/398242)

I know I can add a class to the disabled elements with the second parameter but it adds it to all the disabled dates, including those outside of `minDate` and `maxDate`:

> [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay): A function that takes a date as a parameter and must
>   return an array with:
>
> 0: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable 
> 1:
>   a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default
>   presentation 
> 2: an optional popup tooltip for this date
>
> The function is called for each day in the datepicker before it is
>   displayed.

However the client has requested that only the "booked" dates have a visual indication that the date is not available (distinct from the default disabled state). There will not be many, maybe 4 or 5. It makes sense to me.

Is there some way to customize only the dates disabled by the `beforeShowDay` function in my setup, or another solution to achieve what I'm after? **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/phwjrfdz/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wesley,
I looked at your requirement and looked at the requirement you were in need of and I think as it can be also required by me as it was bit unique in itself so I researched the code and made what you wanted. I am pasting the code below with a bit of explanation of the same:-

**Below is the Jquery Code:-**

```
var disabledDates = [
    '2015-05-06',
    '2015-05-08'
];

$('input').datepicker({
    minDate: '4/30/2015',
    maxDate: '10/1/2015',
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
         var str = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
         var minDateArr = $(this).datepicker( "option", "minDate" ).split('/')

        var minDate = new Date(minDateArr[2],minDateArr[0]-1,minDateArr[1]); //Don't remove the -1 from minDateArr[0]-1 as the Javascript dates starts with 0.
        if ($.inArray(str, disabledDates) != -1){
            return  [false, 'special']
        }
        else if(date < minDate ){
             return [false, 'not-special']
        }
        else{
            return [true,"special"];
        }
    }
});
```

**A bit of Manipulation in the CSS:-**

```
.special span {
    color: red !important; /* should only apply to may 6 and 8 */
}
.not-special span {
    color: green !important; 
}
```

**And the most important there has to be a input tag:-**

```
<input>
```

Also below is the Js Fiddle link for the same:-
http://jsfiddle.net/ckk6hzzu/

Hope this is what was required by you and expecting this will help others where it can be used for booking/reservation sites.