# Dynamically change jQuery datepicker date colours and disable them

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a php function which returns a list of dates that i want to disable on the date picker and also change the colour of the cell to red. Is there any way this can be achieved?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Datepicker API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) you can use the beforeShowDay option to set different class for specific days.

Define the dates to disable:

```
var disabledDates = ["9-5-2011","14-5-2011","15-5-2011"];
```

Implement a function to check the dates:

```
function unavailable(date) {
  var dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  if ($.inArray(dmy, disabledDates) < 0) {
    return [true,"",""];
  } else {
    //the second parameter you can set your css class
    return [false,"red","Day unavailable"];
  }
}
```

Assign the option on the datepicker:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
    altField : '#hiddenFieldID',
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    changeMonth:true,
    minDate: 14,
    beforeShowDay: unavailable //here it is
});
```

[SOURCE](http://tokenposts.blogspot.pt/2011/05/jquery-datepicker-disable-specific.html)

Comment: Hi, i have tried your solution and have adapted it to take an array using json_encode. however when i load my page he date picker disappears. I have added my code above in the question.

Comment: Works fine in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9gwreysL/). Check the console for errors (F12 on chrome/firefox > console tab).

Comment: Ive just realised that when i add var disabledDates = <?php echo json_encode($dates); ?>; to get all the dates that my php function outputs the date picker disappears. Is this the correct way to be getting the dates?

Comment: Try to see what the output is...  Maybe nothing is being echoed and the result ends up being var disabled dates = ; which is invalid. With that said this is one of the reasons why you shouldn't mix JavaScript with PHP code. Better to use a data attribute on the datepicker input and get it inside the function.

Comment: ["20-02-2015"] is echoed. This means the date should be in the javascript but it looks like it isn't

Comment: Well, the date should be formatted like ["20-2-2015"] (without leading zeroes), but that shouldn't prevent the datepicker from loading.

Comment: var_dump produces string(14) "["20-02-2015"]"