# Datetimepicker prevent defaultDate from defaulting to a disabledDate

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, momentjs

Is there a way to prevent the default date from selecting a disabled date?
Here's what I have: 
A default date is set as tomorrow, and dates in a JSON file are disabled, however.. if tomorrow is disabled, it will still be "selected" because it gets defaulted to.

```
$('.datetime-picker').datetimepicker({
  defaultDate: moment().tz('America/Toronto').add('days', 1),
  disabledDates: disabledDatesJSON,
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dates in a JSON files are disabled" ?

Comment: They are stored as moment dates in JSON and passed to disabledDates, for example:
disabledDatesJSON: [moment("02/22/2015"), moment("02/24/2015")]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates