# How can I prevent users making a booking though disabled dates in jQuery UI Date Pickers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using two jQuery date pickers so that a user can book something, upon both date pickers being selected a button called request is displayed. Does anybody know how I could prevent someone trying to make a booking through disabled days by not showing the request button and instead showing an error message? i.e if **from** 13th March is selected then the request button is not shown whenever the **to** date is 15th march as 14th March is disabled.

Hope that makes sense.

[image]

The disabled days are being called from my database and being stored in a JavaScript variable called bookedDays.

The JavaScript code I am using is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#request').hide();
    $('.days').html('Please select a date range of at least the same day. <br/> <i>Max booking: 2 Months.</i>');
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: new Date(),
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      minDate: new Date(),
      maxDate: "+1M",
      beforeShowDay: isAvailable,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        var day = $("#from").datepicker('getDate');
day.setDate(day.getDate()+1);
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", day );

      }
    });

    $( "#to" ).datepicker({

      defaultDate: new Date(),
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      minDate: ("#to"),
      maxDate: ("+2M"),
      beforeShowDay: isAvailable,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });

    function isAvailable(date){
    var dateAsString = date.getFullYear().toString() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1).toString() + "-" + date.getDate();
    var result = $.inArray( dateAsString, bookedDays ) ===-1 ? [true] : [false];
    return result;
  }


    $('#to').on('change',function(){
     var days = (daydiff(parseDate($('#from').val()), parseDate($('#to').val())));
      var cogs = $('#cogsday').html();
      cogs = cogs.replace(/\D/g,'');
      var x = days;
      var y = cogs * x;
      $('.days').html('You have chosen to borrow this item for <b>'+ days + '</b> days at a cost of <b>' + y + '</b> cogs.<br/><br/>');
        if(days){
            if (borrowercogs >= (y)) {
        $('#request').show();
      } else {
           $('#request').hide();
           $('.days').html('You have chosen to borrow this item for <b>'+ days + '</b> days at a cost of <b>' + y + '</b> cogs.<br/><i style=color:red>You do not have enough cogs to borrow for this duration.</i><br/>');
      }
        }

      $('#request').click(function() {

                var cogs = $('#cogsday').html();

                cogs = cogs.replace(/\D/g,'');

        var x = days ;

        var y = cogs * x;
        $('#total').text(y);
        $('#nameID').val(y);
        $('#days').text(days);
        $('#daysID').val(days);

        });
    })

    function parseDate(str) {
    var mdy = str.split('/')
    return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
}

function daydiff(first, second) {
    return Math.round((second-first)/(1000*60*60*24));
}

  });
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates

Comment: @Mike - Isn't that just disabling the dates though? I already have them disabling ok but I want to prevent booking from before a disabled date to after a disabled date

Comment: flip the boolean, from == -1 to !=-1

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood your original question... I think I get it now, you can do this kind of validation after the user has selected dates, but you cannot do it with any native form control method for the jQuery datepicker, it does not have this functionality (disallowing ranges of dates that include disabled dates.) Although, it's quite simple if you just loop through the range of dates and check to see if any of those dates are disabled.

Comment: Yeah sorry for not making it more clear but its hard to explain. Do you have any idea how to loop through the range of dates to see if any are disabled or know of anywhere I could get help with this? :)

Comment: Check my answer again, I've improved it, this time it should be pretty clear what you need to do with your code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATED***

*[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mgleeson/vghkaya3/)*

```
var array = ["2015-03-14","2015-03-15","2015-03-16"]

var _selectedDay = "";
var _cascadeDisabled = false;

$('#from').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var _date = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        var _isDisabledDate = array.indexOf(_date) != -1;      

        return [ array.indexOf(_date) == -1 ]
    },
    onClose: function(dateStr, event) {
        _selectedDay = dateStr;
    }
});

$('#to').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var _date = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        var _isDisabledDate = array.indexOf(_date) != -1;
        if(_selectedDay.length && _isDisabledDate 
          && _selectedDay < _date) {
            _cascadeDisabled = true;
        }

        if(_cascadeDisabled) return false;

        return [ array.indexOf(_date) == -1 ]
    },
    onClose: function(dateStr, event) {
        _cascadeDisabled = false;
    }
});


$("#clear").click(function() {
    $("input[type='text']").val("");
});
```

As you can see, what we're doing here is setting a global variable with the "FROM" datepicker, and then in the "TO" datepicker, we loop through until we hit a disabled date, from then on forward we set the global variable "cascade" to cascade all the future dates to be disabled, effectively making it impossible to book a range of dates that includes a disabled date.

Comment: I'm not too sure how to go about adding this to my code as my beforeShowDay is already calling the isAvailable function?

Comment: Ignore this, I'm rewriting the proper answer now. but to put it basically, you're going to cascade the disabled dates as you loop/iterate through them

Comment: No problem. I looked there and now understand the need to loop through the array but just not sure how to do it with the code I already have

Comment: Check my answer now/the JSFiddle, it doesn't have your to/from setup, but you can port my code into yours, you just need to set your "from date" from the "from datepicker" and then use my code on your "to datepicker"

Comment: It's looking good, thanks very much for your time on this. On my original code the variable bookedDays contained all the disabled dates (set in php file) rather than hard coding them in like the above example. I have tried var array = bookedDays. Do you know how I could fix that?

Comment: You should be able to assign the dates into the array, I'm not sure what your "bookedDays" array/object looks like, could you post a JSFiddle with a mockup of the structure of this variable?

Comment: As the data is being read from my database it is difficult to replicate but i have put the code in to the following fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4nvsLkL4/