# JQuery UI Datepicker - Problems displaying only the dates in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using the jQuery UI datepicker as part of a booking engine allowing a user to select from only available dates.

My code is as follows:

```
var availableDates =  ["16/06/2014", "16/06/2014", "23/06/2014", "27/06/2014", "30/06/2014", "02/07/2014", "07/07/2014", "07/07/2014", "11/07/2014", "14/07/2014", "14/07/2014", "16/07/2014", "18/07/2014", "21/07/2014", "21/07/2014", "25/07/2014", "28/07/2014", "28/07/2014", "01/08/2014", "04/08/2014", "04/08/2014", "06/08/2014", "08/08/2014", "11/08/2014", "11/08/2014", "13/08/2014", "15/08/2014", "18/08/2014", "18/08/2014", "25/08/2014", "01/09/2014", "01/09/2014", "08/09/2014", "12/09/2014", "12/09/2014"]
```

This code was adapted from another solution on on SO that can be found here except they are doing the opposite and excluding the items in the list. How do I adapt my code to display only the dates found in the array above?

My code example is based upon this post:
[Jquery UI datepicker. Disable array of Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates)

```
    $('.departureDate').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: available,
        altFormat: 'yy.mm.dd',
        altField: '#cultureDate'
    });

    function available(date) {
        var dateString = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', date);
        if(availableDates.indexOf(dateString) == -1){
            console.log(dateString + " " + false);
            return false;
        }else{
            console.log(dateString + " " + true);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed from the example that I need to wrap my true / false values in an array with only one item hence the code should be:

```
function available(date) {
        var dateString = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', date);
        if(availableDates.indexOf(dateString) == -1){
            console.log(dateString + " " + false);
            return [false];
        }else{
            console.log(dateString + " " + true);
            return [true];
        }
    }
```