# specific dates in DatePicker

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, xforms

I am using a datepicker in a MVC4 application.

But I want to select just a specific range in the DatePicker. Because now there is  a dropdownlist where the user can select a date. But the dropdownlist has to be replaced by a datepicker.

I have a method for the AvailableDates, like this:

```
 public AvailableDates GetAvailableDates(string branchPublicId, string servicePublicId)
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = CreateHttpRequest("calendar-backend/public/api/v1/branches/" + branchPublicId + "/services/" + servicePublicId + "/dates", HttpMethod.Get, "application/json");
            string json = Get(httpRequest);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AvailableDates>(json);
        }
```

And this is the JQuery from the DatePicker:

```
; (function ($) {
    $(function () {
        $("form.xforms-form").bind({
            XForms_Enrich: function (e) {
                if ($.fn.datepicker) {
                    $("input.qmatic-dateslot", e.args.data).each(function () {
                        var inp = $(this);
                        if (inp.is(":disabled")) return;
                        var tabindex = inp.attr("tabindex");

                        var dateFormat = $.xforms.getProperty(inp, 'dateFormat') || 'dd-MM';
                        dateFormat = dateFormat.replace(/m/g, '0').replace(/h/gi, '0').replace(/t/g, '').replace(/M/g, 'm').replace('yyyy', 'yy');

                        $("#" + inp.attr("id") + " ~ button.ui-datepicker-trigger").attr("tabindex", tabindex);

                        var clearBtn = $('<button class="ui-datepicker-clear" type="button" tabindex="' + tabindex + '">x</button>').click(function () { inp.val(''); inp.change(); return false; });
                        inp.after(clearBtn);

                        inp.datepicker({
                            dateFormat: dateFormat,
                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear: false,
                            showWeek: true,
                            firstDay: 1,
                            yearRange: "c-100:c+15",
                            showOn: inp.hasClass("ui-date-picker-onfocus") ? "focus" : "button"
                        })
                    });
                    $("#ui-datepicker-div").hide();
                }
            }
        })
    })
})(jQuery);
```

But how to use that method in the DatePicker?

Thank you

But how to use this piece:

```
var array = ["2013-03-14","2013-03-15","2013-03-16"]

$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
```

In the DatePicker plugin?

Thank you

I try it like this:

```
; (function ($) {
    $(function () {
        $("form.xforms-form").bind({
            XForms_Enrich: function (e) {
                if ($.fn.datepicker) {

                    var array = ["2013-03-14", "2013-03-15", "2013-03-16"]
                    $("input.qmatic-dateslot", e.args.data).each(function () {

                        beforeShowDay: function(date){
                            var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                            return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
                        }



                        var inp = $(this);
                        if (inp.is(":disabled")) return;
                        var tabindex = inp.attr("tabindex");

                        var dateFormat = $.xforms.getProperty(inp, 'dateFormat') || 'dd-MM';
                        dateFormat = dateFormat.replace(/m/g, '0').replace(/h/gi, '0').replace(/t/g, '').replace(/M/g, 'm').replace('yyyy', 'yy');

                        $("#" + inp.attr("id") + " ~ button.ui-datepicker-trigger").attr("tabindex", tabindex);

                        var clearBtn = $('<button class="ui-datepicker-clear" type="button" tabindex="' + tabindex + '">x</button>').click(function () { inp.val(''); inp.change(); return false; });
                        inp.after(clearBtn);

                        inp.datepicker({
                            dateFormat: dateFormat,
                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear: false,
                            showWeek: true,
                            firstDay: 1,
                            yearRange: "c-100:c+15",
                            showOn: inp.hasClass("ui-date-picker-onfocus") ? "focus" : "button"
                        })
                    });
                    $("#ui-datepicker-div").hide();
                }
            }
        })
    })
})(jQuery);
```

But then by date I get the message: Expected Identifier

if I do it like this:

```
 ; (function ($) {
        $(function () {
            $("form.xforms-form").bind({
                XForms_Enrich: function (e) {
                    if ($.fn.datepicker) {
                        $("input.qmatic-dateslot", e.args.data).each(function () {

                            //var array = ["2013-03-14", "2013-03-15", "2013-03-16"]
                            var inp = $(this);
                            if (inp.is(":disabled")) return;
                            var tabindex = inp.attr("tabindex");

                            var dateFormat = $.xforms.getProperty(inp, 'dateFormat') || 'd-M-yy';
                            dateFormat = dateFormat.replace(/m/g, '0').replace(/h/gi, '0').replace(/t/g, '').replace(/M/g, 'm').replace('yyyy', 'yy');

                            $("#" + inp.attr("id") + " ~ button.ui-datepicker-trigger").attr("tabindex", tabindex);

                            var clearBtn = $('<button class="ui-datepicker-clear" type="button" tabindex="' + tabindex + '">x</button>').click(function () { inp.val(''); inp.change(); return false; });
                            inp.after(clearBtn);

                            inp.datepicker({
                                dateFormat: dateFormat,
                                changeMonth: true,
                                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                                    var arr = ["2015-03-14", "2015-03-15", "2015-03-16"]; // Should be your json array of dates coming from server
                                    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                                    return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
                                },
                                changeYear: false,
                                showWeek: true,
                                firstDay: 1,
                                yearRange: "c-100:c+15",
                                showOn: inp.hasClass("ui-date-picker-onfocus") ? "focus" : "button"
                            })
                        });
                        $("#ui-datepicker-div").hide();
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    })(jQuery);
```

Then I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: array is not defined
```

but If I do it like this:

```
 ; (function ($) {
        $(function () {
            $("form.xforms-form").bind({
                XForms_Enrich: function (e) {
                    if ($.fn.datepicker) {
                        $("input.qmatic-dateslot", e.args.data).each(function () {

                            var array = ["2013-03-14", "2013-03-15", "2013-03-16"]
                            var inp = $(this);
                            if (inp.is(":disabled")) return;
                            var tabindex = inp.attr("tabindex");

                            var dateFormat = $.xforms.getProperty(inp, 'dateFormat') || 'd-M-yy';
                            dateFormat = dateFormat.replace(/m/g, '0').replace(/h/gi, '0').replace(/t/g, '').replace(/M/g, 'm').replace('yyyy', 'yy');

                            $("#" + inp.attr("id") + " ~ button.ui-datepicker-trigger").attr("tabindex", tabindex);

                            var clearBtn = $('<button class="ui-datepicker-clear" type="button" tabindex="' + tabindex + '">x</button>').click(function () { inp.val(''); inp.change(); return false; });
                            inp.after(clearBtn);

                            inp.datepicker({
                                dateFormat: dateFormat,
                                changeMonth: true,
                                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                                    //var arr = ["2015-03-14", "2015-03-15", "2015-03-16"]; // Should be your json array of dates coming from server
                                    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                                    return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
                                },
                                changeYear: false,
                                showWeek: true,
                                firstDay: 1,
                                yearRange: "c-100:c+15",
                                showOn: inp.hasClass("ui-date-picker-onfocus") ? "focus" : "button"
                            })
                        });
                        $("#ui-datepicker-div").hide();
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    })(jQuery);
```

The dates that are in the array are also selectable

Thank you

I try to call the method with a ajax call, like this:

```
 inp.datepicker({
                            dateFormat: dateFormat,
                            changeMonth: true,
                            $.ajax({

                                type: "GET",
                                url: "QMatic/GetAvailableDates",
                                data: dataString,
                                dataType: "json",




}),


                            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                                var array = ["2015-03-14", "2015-03-15", "2015-03-16"];  
                                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                                return [array.indexOf(string) == -1];
                            },
                            changeYear: false,
                            showWeek: true,
                            firstDay: 1,
                            yearRange: "c-100:c+15",
                            showOn: inp.hasClass("ui-date-picker-onfocus") ? "focus" : "button"
                        })
```

But $.ajax is not recognisable.

Thank you

I also tried like this, to call the method. the class name of the method is: QMatic:

```
  inp.datepicker({
                            dateFormat: dateFormat,
                            changeMonth: true,


                                type: "GET",
                                url: "~/QMatic/GetAvailableDates",
                                data: dataString,
                                dataType: "json",

                            //beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                            //    var array = ["2015-03-14", "2015-03-15", "2015-03-16"];  
                            //    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                            //    return [array.indexOf(string) == -1];
                            //},
                            changeYear: false,
                            showWeek: true,
                            firstDay: 1,
                            yearRange: "c-100:c+15",
                            showOn: inp.hasClass("ui-date-picker-onfocus") ? "focus" : "button"

                        })
```

I am also using xforms, like this:

```
 <xf:select1 ref="serviceid" incremental="true">
                <xf:label>Selecteer product</xf:label>
                <xf:item>
                  <xf:label>
                    <xf:output value="concat('(',exf:label(.),')')" />
                  </xf:label>
                  <xf:value></xf:value>
                </xf:item>
                <xf:itemset nodeset="instance('qmatic')/services/item">
                  <xf:label ref="name" />
                  <xf:value ref="value" />
                </xf:itemset>
                <xf:action ev:event="xforms-value-changed">
                  <xf:setvalue ref="../dateslot" value="''" />
                  <xf:setvalue ref="../timeslot" value="''" />
                  <xf:setvalue ref="instance('qmatic')/dateslots/@result" value="qmatic:getavailabledates(instance('qmatic')/dateslots, instance('')/afspraak/branchid, instance('')/afspraak/serviceid)" />
                </xf:action>
              </xf:select1>


                <xf:input ref="dateInputQmatic" incremental="true" class="qmatic-dateslot">
                    <xf:label>Selecteer datum</xf:label>
                    <xf:action ev:event="xforms-value-changed">
                        <xf:setvalue ref="../timeslot" value="''" />
                        <xf:setvalue ref="instance('qmatic')/timeslots/@result" value="qmatic:getavailabletimes(instance('qmatic')/timeslots, instance('')/afspraak/branchid, instance('')/afspraak/serviceid, instance('')/afspraak/dateslot)" />
                    </xf:action>
                </xf:input>

              <xf:select1 ref="dateslot" incremental="true">
                <xf:label>Selecteer datum</xf:label>
                <xf:item>
                  <xf:label>
                    <xf:output value="concat('(',exf:label(.),')')" />
                  </xf:label>
                  <xf:value></xf:value>
                </xf:item>
                <xf:itemset nodeset="instance('qmatic')/dateslots/item">
                  <xf:label ref="name" />
                  <xf:value ref="value" />
                </xf:itemset>
                <xf:action ev:event="xforms-value-changed">
                  <xf:setvalue ref="../timeslot" value="''" />
                  <xf:setvalue ref="instance('qmatic')/timeslots/@result" value="qmatic:getavailabletimes(instance('qmatic')/timeslots, instance('')/afspraak/branchid, instance('')/afspraak/serviceid, instance('')/afspraak/dateslot)" />
                </xf:action>
              </xf:select1>
```

so here are the available dates in a dropdownlist:

```
 <xf:select1 ref="dateslot" incremental="true">
                <xf:label>Selecteer datum</xf:label>
                <xf:item>
                  <xf:label>
                    <xf:output value="concat('(',exf:label(.),')')" />
                  </xf:label>
                  <xf:value></xf:value>
                </xf:item>
                <xf:itemset nodeset="instance('qmatic')/dateslots/item">
                  <xf:label ref="name" />
                  <xf:value ref="value" />
                </xf:itemset>
                <xf:action ev:event="xforms-value-changed">
                  <xf:setvalue ref="../timeslot" value="''" />
                  <xf:setvalue ref="instance('qmatic')/timeslots/@result" value="qmatic:getavailabletimes(instance('qmatic')/timeslots, instance('')/afspraak/branchid, instance('')/afspraak/serviceid, instance('')/afspraak/dateslot)" />
                </xf:action>
              </xf:select1>
```

and this is the datepicker:

```
<xf:input ref="dateInputQmatic" incremental="true" class="qmatic-dateslot">
                    <xf:label>Selecteer datum</xf:label>                   
                </xf:input>
```

what also has to return  the only availbe dates from the method:

```
GetAvailableDates
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into the beforeshowday event in datepicker. Look at the following link for an example -

[Jquery UI datepicker. Disable array of Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates)

Updated code

```
inp.datepicker({
    dateFormat: dateFormat,
    changeMonth: true,
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var arr = ["2013-03-14", "2013-03-15", "2013-03-16"] ; // Should be your json array of dates coming from server
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    },
    changeYear: false,
    showWeek: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    yearRange: "c-100:c+15",
    showOn: inp.hasClass("ui-date-picker-onfocus") ? "focus" : "button"
})
```

Comment: Hi Akhil, but how to use that in a Jquery Plugin? I edit my post. Thank you

Comment: you need to add "beforeShowDay" along with other properties.

Comment: Thank you. I udated the post

Comment: Oke, that works very nice. But how now to use that method. Because now it is static(hard coded). But how to make it dynamically with the method?

Comment: Don't populate your array inside datepicker. Define it outside the datepicker scope.

Comment: I Updated my post.with the method. But now the datepicker is even not visible. But how to use $.ajax inside the method?

Comment: So using that method(GetAvailableDates) returns the available dates and the rest has to be disabled in the datePicker.

Comment: Sorry, ofcourse not server side with Ajax call. But just client side. Because the available dates are already set, so you only have to get the avaible dates visible in the DatePicker and the other dates are disabled.