# Datepicker select date after 3 days

Tags: javascript, datepicker

How can I edit DatePicker to start select dates after 3 days of actual date.

I tried :

```
 $('#thedate').datepicker("setDate", "+3");
```

But I want to make disable **today and the two days after today**.

This is a fiddle of my Datepicker.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/521/)

Comment: Do you mean you want to disable from today to next three days?

Comment: Yes, sorry. question edited

Comment: Hope these links help you, use disable specific date in datepicker: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates or http://www.spiceforms.com/blog/how-to-disable-dates-in-jquery-datepicker-a-short-guide/

Comment: I assume that you use jquery ui datepicker. Use "beforeShowDay" function you can pass the array of dates to it.. and you can disable the next three days by passing that dates to function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try *minDate* option like this:

```
$('#thedate').datepicker({
    minDate: "+3",
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
$('#thedate').datepicker("setDate", "+3");
```

See updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/522/)

Comment: Perhaps set some individual CSS settings to class `ui-datepicker-today`