# Jquery datepicker enable dates from array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to enable just some specified dates in datepicker. In my case the values inside the variable "onlyThisDates".
Should I use enabledDates option to solve this or ..?
I do not want disable the values in the array. The other way around. I want disable everything and just enable the values in the array.

If someone could help it would be great.

```
<input id="openDatepick></input>
```

```
var onlyThisDates = ['09/11/2015', '10/11/2015', '11/11/2015'];    

var nowDate = new Date();
var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

$('#openDatepick').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    startDate: today

}).on('changeDate', function (e) {
    //$('this').datepicker('hide');
});
$("#remove").on("click", function () {
    $('.datepicker-days').hide();
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates duplicate

Comment: Hi, I dont want disable the values in the array. I will  explain it above better..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery UI datepicker. Disable array of Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates)

Answer (score 6):

In `beforeShowDay` function: for any date you return false - that will be disabled and for any date any thing other than false is returned that day will be enabled.

Based on this your `beforeShowDay` should be something like the following:-

```
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var dt_ddmmyyyy = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
        return (onlyThisDates.indexOf(dt_ddmmyyyy) != -1);
    }
```

Note that I've added 1 to `getMonth()` as month in javascript starts from 0.

See [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/hxdjz9cj/).

---

> EDIT: Based on comment

In the `beforeShowDay` function we can define css, tooltips etc. For example instead of returning true we can return a css-class.

```
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var dt_ddmmyyyy = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
        if (onlyThisDates.indexOf(dt_ddmmyyyy) != -1) {
            return {
                tooltip: 'This date is enabled',
                classes: 'active'
            };
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/hxdjz9cj/2/).

Also see [this link](https://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) for different functionalities available with bootstrap datepicker.

Comment: Many thanks for your help :-) Is there a way to highlight it with color within the datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

Following code will disable days of week using datepicker, property 'daysOfWeekDisabled'
needs array of week day id

```
$(".dateControl").datepicker({
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [1,2,3],
            startDate: new Date(),
            autoclose: true
        })
```