# Disable recurring dates using jQuery Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to disable the 2nd Saturday, 4th Saturday, Sunday and public holidays, throughout the year, using jQuery Calendar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15400806/2270492, Have a look at this

Comment: Please write code what have you tried so far.

Comment: @Hemal  please read question it is for calender.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1067759/How-To-disable-nd-th-saturday-sunday-and-Holiday-d may help u or u can use datepicker to disable specific date using jquery

Comment: I also suggest to use jQuery datepicker.

Comment: @Hemal how we can use datepicker instead of calander.

Comment: @AnkitKathiriya  
stackoverflow.com/a/15400806/2270492

Comment: @Hemal the my question is how we can use datepicker in place of calander.

Comment: @AnkitKathiriya include js file in html and $(selectedID).datepicker({//disable date logic});

Answer (score 0):

> Jquery Calendar plugin provide you a option "beforeShowDay", you can 
>   find more information on DataPickerUI
>
> To Disable 2nd Saturday & 4th Saturday, you need to first calculate the sat or sunday of specific month then disable those dates, like we did for others calendars
>
> sample code calculate sat & sunday https://www.hscripts.com/scripts/JavaScript/second-fourth.php
>
> Created plunker for you,
>   https://plnkr.co/edit/inBYY748BptaCd7Ulwwg?p=preview

```
                //To disable Sundays you need to find out the Day of current date.
            $(function () {
                var publicHolidays = [
                  [11, 28, 2015],
                  [11, 30, 2015]
                ];

                $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                        var day = date.getDay();
                        return [(day !== 0), ''];
                    }
                });

                //To disable public holidays create an array with you holiday list then
                //return false when you browse calender.

                $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
                    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                        for (i = 0; i < publicHolidays.length; i++) {
                            if (date.getMonth() == publicHolidays[i][0] &&
                              date.getDate() == publicHolidays[i][1] &&
                              date.getFullYear() == publicHolidays[i][2]) {
                                return [false];
                            }
                        }
                        return [true];
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here's a couple of functions for the second/fourth Saturday part of the problem.

Both functions accept an instance of javascript `Date()` and return `true` or `false`. You can use either one.

```
function is2ndOr4thSat_1(date) {
    var day = date.getDay(),
        week = Math.floor(date.getDate() / 7);
    return day == 6 && (week == 1 || week == 3)
}
```

Hopefully `is2ndOr4thSat_1()` is self explanatory.

```
function is2ndOr4thSat_2(date) {
    var d = date.getDate(),
        offset = (((1 + date.getDay() - d) % 7) + 7) % 7;
    return !((offset + d) % 14);
}
```

`is2ndOr4thSat_2()` is more obscure.

The expression `(((1 + date.getDay() - d) % 7) + 7) % 7` finds the offset of the first of the month from a nominal zero (the 1st's preceding Saturday), using a true modulo algorithm that caters for negative numbers.

Then `(offset + d) % 14` returns `0` if `date` is either 14 or 28 days ahead of the nominal zero, and `!` converts to a boolean of the required sense (`true` for qualifying Saturdays otherwise `false`).