# Angular 2 datepicker component that enables to disable specific dates

Tags: jquery, angular, datepicker

is there an angular 2 datepicker component that enables me to disable an array of specific dates?

I know that creating a custom wrapper for jquery datepicker is an option.

I found these 3 datepickers, but no one seem to capable of disabling certain dates.

https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker

https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-datepicker

www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

EDIT:

I will be getting the list in an http request. In addition, I need to disable all dates before the current date.

EDIT2:

It is a reservation use case. I need to disable all dates before today and I need to disable all dates from an array I will get in an http request.

The usage of validator is not a good option, because the user needs to see what he cannot choose.

EDIT3:

I have just found this one https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/tree/master/components/datepicker, I will go with this one and later post an answer.

Comment: You can disable using jkuri if you modified the html they created. I used it before.

Comment: @Herm Luna  see my edit

Answer (score 1):

This one has it.
http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

See the Date Restriction section

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateValue" minDate="-1m" maxDate="+1m" [readonlyInput]="true">></p-calendar>
```

+it uses jquery UI datepicker so you can use some of this: 
[Jquery UI datepicker. Disable array of Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates)

But...

**Best way** of doing this is probably just make an validator for this, and prevent user of selecting the value. You are 3rd party independent with this solution. Which can be pretty helpful in angular2 dynamic world.

**AFTER QUESTION EDIT**

> I will be getting the list in an http request. In addition, I need to
>   disable all dates before the current date.

If you don't want to code it in angular (validator or some change detection). The primeNG restrict will give you ability to disable a range of dates. (max/min date)

Comment: See edit: you can take advantage of primeng using jquery ui, so you can try to restrict those dates there

Comment: Since he's using angular2. Why don't do it in angular way?

Comment: Just made the edit ;) why you just don't post a proper answer instead of only pointing out other's mistakes?

Comment: I'm not pointing it. I am just asking. I know your answer is perfect.

Comment: Doing this angular2 way is simply the best answer, but the question was about choosing 3rd library.

Comment: What do you mean by angular2 way?

Comment: Validator is the simplest solution, but I am afraid it will hurt the ux experience.

Comment: @Michael.D 1. see my answer edit 2.you can use some change detection + validation in angular2 (on datepicker control). Are you familiar with forms validation?

Comment: @jmachnik the validator/change option is not a valid option, the user will select the date he wants to choose and than I will present him with the information that is not available. This breaks on of the basic rules of the usability.

Comment: Of course. But if your dates are just ranges (your edit shows that it's the case) you can use the primeng restrict, can't you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125891/discussion-between-jmachnik-and-michael-d).

Comment: Perfect answer. I don't know why is it (-1) instead of (+50).

Comment: PrimeNG not using jquery for p-calendar component it is all native angular 2 now they are on their version 4.