# Use php array to disable dates in datepicker and times in timepicker from onSelect in DatePicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker, timepicker

I have a datepicker input and a timepicker input that I'd like to use to schedule a person for appointments.

When the user clicks on the input to open the datepicker menu, I'd like to grey out specific datetimes.  I've got a php function that returns this array of datetimes in in 'Y-m-d H:i:s' string format.  But I dont' know how to use that function's return value to give the javascript function what it needs to disable a range of dates in datepicker.

In the onSelect event of my datepicker, I want it to enable/disable time options in my timepicker according to which timeslots are booked for that day.  But I don't know how.

1. Datepicker uses beforeshowDay: to disable booked dates
2. user selects date from datepicker
3. Datepicker enables/disables times in the timepicker

I did find out how to disable timeranges in the timepicker [Here](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/). the code example is this:

```
$('input.timepicker').timepicker({
    'disableTimeRanges': [
        ['1am', '2am'],
        ['3am', '4:01am']
    ]
});
```

But that's how I'd disable the time ranges from within the scope of the timepicker.  I don't know how to disable them from BeforeShowDay in datepicker?

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#datepickerListAppointments" ).datepicker(
        {
            minDate:'0',
            beforeShowDay:
            function(dt)
            {   // need to disable days other than tuesday and wednesday too.
                return [dt.getDay() === 2 || dt.getDay() === 3, ""];
            },
            onSelect : function(){
                should disable/enable timepicker times from here?
            }
        });

        $('input.timepicker').timepicker({
            timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
            interval: 90,
            minTime: '9',
            maxTime: '10:30am',
            defaultTime: '9',
            startTime: '9:00',
            dynamic: false,
            dropdown: true,
            scrollbar: false                
        });

    });
```

This is the function that gives the datetimes, in case it helps to know.

```
function get_next_open_appointments($numAppointments, $timeSlotToExclude = "")
{
    global $db;
    $whereCondition = "WHERE FirstName = :null ";
    if ($timeSlotToExclude != "")
    {
        $whereCondition .= "AND AppointmentTime != '$timeSlotToExclude' ";
    }

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT AppointmentTime FROM appointments
              $whereCondition
              ORDER BY AppointmentTime ASC LIMIT $numAppointments";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':null', "");
    $statement->execute();
    $datesArray = array();
    while ($row = $statement->fetch()) 
    {
        array_push($datesArray, $row['AppointmentTime']);
    }
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $datesArray;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Hugo De Carmo pointed me in the right direction and I got the dates to disable/enable appropriately.  However, I don't know how to use the datetimes that I pulled in code below to disable/enable times in the timepicker.

Here is the new code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // uses php to get open appointments, and put them in a javascript array
        <?php $datetime_openings = get_next_open_appointments(200);
        $date_openings = array();
        foreach ($datetime_openings as $dt)
        {
            array_push($date_openings, substr($dt,0,10)); // just the date part
        }

        $json_date_openings = json_encode($date_openings);
        echo "var arr_Openings = ". $json_date_openings . ";\n";
        ?>

        $( "#datepickerOpenAppointments" ).datepicker(
        {
            minDate:'0',
            beforeShowDay:
            function(dt)
            {
                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', dt);
                var bFound = (arr_Openings.indexOf(string) != -1);
                return [ bFound ]; 
            },
            onSelect : function(){
               //    Should disable/enable time ranges here?
        });

        $('input.timepicker').timepicker({
            timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
            interval: 90,
            minTime: '9',
            maxTime: '10:30am',
            defaultTime: '9',
            startTime: '9:00',
            dynamic: false,
            dropdown: true,
            scrollbar: false                
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,
sorry i didn't use beforeshowDay
select date 2017-7-14 and 2017-7-17 and see

```js
var disabledDateTime = {
  '2017-7-14':[
   ['2:30am','3:00am'],
    ['6:30am','9:00am']
  ],
 '2017-7-17':[
   ['1:00am','3:00am'],
    ['5:30am','7:00am'],
    ['11:30am','2:00pm']
  ]
};

$(function() {
  $('#pickTime').timepicker();
  $('#pickDate').datepicker({
    'format': 'yyyy-m-d',
    'autoclose': true
  }).on('changeDate',function(e){
    var ts = new Date(e.date);
    var m = ts.getMonth()+1;
    var dt = ts.getFullYear() + '-' + m + '-' + ts.getDate();
    var opt = {'disableTimeRanges': []}
    if(typeof(disabledDateTime[dt])!='undefined'){
      $('#pickTime').timepicker('setTime', '');
      opt = {'disableTimeRanges': disabledDateTime[dt]}
    }
    $('#pickTime').timepicker('option',opt);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/lib/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/lib/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>

<input id="pickDate" type="text" class="date" />
<input id="pickTime" type="text" class="time" />
```

Comment: var disabledDateTime = { 
'2017-7-14':[ 
['2:30am','3:00am'], 
['6:30am','9:00am'] 
], 
'2017-7-17':[ 
['1:00am','3:00am'], 
['5:30am','7:00am'], 
['11:30am','2:00pm'] 
] 
}; 
But i want to display this dynamically from db values such as date,starttime,endtime using php.how can i do this?

Comment: var disabledDateTime = {'2017-7-14':[['2:30am','3:00am'],['6:30am','9:00am']],
      '2017-7-17':[['1:00am','3:00am'],['5:30am','2:00pm']]};
the above javascript storing two values into a variable(disabledDateTime) but i want
to store dynamically values into that variable(disabledDateTime) using php from database

Comment: @hearthacker you can use ajax to retrieve the data(json) and set var disabledDateTime at any times.

Answer (score 3):

Someone already answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates).

Anyway, the following code should give you an insight on how to solve the problem.

```
// supose your script return a json similar to the following
{
    "data": [
        // ...
        "17-07-11"
    ]
}

$(function() {
  $.getJSON("/path/to/script", function(response){
    $('#datepickerListAppointments').datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: function(dt) {
        var config = [];
        config[1] = 'class';

        if ((dt.getDay() === 2) || (dt.getDay() === 3)) {
          config[0] = false;
          return config;
        }

        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', dt);
        config[0] = (response.data.indexOf(string) === -1);
        return config;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I've assumed that you're exchanging data with the server using some kind of API, hence the use of [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), if you want to handle server errors then I suggest you to use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) combining with [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

**Edit 1**

You can extract everything from your date using the class [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php), here is a snippet:

```
$openings = array();

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("y/m/d H:i", "17/07/15 08:30");

if (!isset($openings[$date->format("y-m-d")])) {
    $openings[$date->format("y-m-d")] = array();
}

$openings[$date->format("y-m-d")][] = array(
    "hour" => $date->format("Ha"),
    "minute" => $date->format("i")
);

/* result
array(1) {
  ["17-07-15"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["hour"]=>
      string(4) "08am"
      ["minute"]=>
      string(2) "30"
    }
  }
}
*/
```

Then you can disable the time in timepicker based on date, you'll probably need to register a callback function in your datepicker to update the timepicker based on the chosen date or you'll have to override the timepicker with new settings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can dinamically update timepicker `disableTimeRanges` inside the `onSelect` function using the [`option`](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#methods) method of the timepicker component.

I'm supposing that:

- You are using jQuery UI [datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) (since you didn't tag your question with `twitter-bootstrap` and `bootstrap-datepicker` has no `minDate` option)
- You are using the first version of `get_next_open_appointments` that returns an array of datetimes (like `['2017-07-25 09:30:00', ...]` see `fakeDisabledTimes` in the snippet)

I'm using momentjs in order to simplify dates managment. In the following code, I've used moment parsing functions ([`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) and [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)), [`isSame`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/), [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) and [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). Note that moment tokens are different from PHP tokens.

Here a complete working sample:

```js
var fakeDisabledTimes = [
  '2017-07-25 09:30:00', '2017-07-26 10:00:00',
  '2017-08-01 09:00:00', '2017-08-02 09:30:00',
  '2017-08-08 10:30:00', '2017-08-09 10:00:00',
  '2017-07-15 09:30:00', '2017-07-16 10:00:00'
];

$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#datepickerListAppointments" ).datepicker({
    minDate:'0',
    beforeShowDay:
    function(dt){
      // need to disable days other than tuesday and wednesday too.
      return [dt.getDay() === 2 || dt.getDay() === 3, ""];
    },
    onSelect : function(dateText){
      //should disable/enable timepicker times from here!
      // parse selected date into moment object
      var selDate = moment(dateText, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
      // init array of disabled times
      var disabledTimes = [];
      // for each appoinment returned by the server
      for(var i=0; i<fakeDisabledTimes.length; i++){
        // parse appoinment datetime into moment object
        var m = moment(fakeDisabledTimes[i]);
        // check if appointment is in the selected day
        if( selDate.isSame(m, 'day') ){
          // create a 30 minutes range of disabled time
          var entry = [
            m.format('h:mm a'),
            m.clone().add(30, 'm').format('h:mm a')
          ];
          // add the range to disabled times array
          disabledTimes.push(entry);
        }
      }
      // dinamically update disableTimeRanges option
      $('input.timepicker').timepicker('option', 'disableTimeRanges', disabledTimes);
    }
  });

  $('input.timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'h:i a',
    interval: 90,
    minTime: '9',
    maxTime: '10:30am',
    defaultTime: '9',
    startTime: '9:00',
    dynamic: false,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: false                
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.10.0/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.10.0/jquery.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input id="datepickerListAppointments" type="text">
<input class="timepicker" type="text">
```