# How to disable multiple dates in datepicker (Bootstrap, CodeIgniter)?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am trying to create a datepicker, and I need to disable multiple dates from it.

I managed to disable one date by doing this :

```
$attributes = array(
                'id'    => 'end',
                'name'  => 'end',
                'data-provide'          => "datepicker",
                'data-date-format'      => "dd/mm/yyyy",
                'data-date-dates-disabled'  => "14/07/2017",
                'value' => date(mdate('%d/%m/%Y')),
        );
$html .= form_input($attributes);
```

However, when I try to add multiples dates to the line `data-date-dates-disabled'   => "14/07/2017",`, it does not work.
I have tried doing `"14/07/2017,15/07/2017"`, `"[14/07/2017,15/07/2017]"`, `"14/07/2017 15/07/2017"`, but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know how to do that ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it was indeed a bug, I had to upgrade my bootstrap-datepicker to > v1.7.0 [where that bug was fixed](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#bugfixes-1)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this one in jsfiddle, seems working fine. give it a shot.

[Jquery UI datepicker. Disable array of Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates)

Comment: thank you, I'll give it a try if I can't find a php based solution

Comment: from where you are getting the dates which you will disable in the datepicker??

Comment: If you are getting the dates from db. You can get the dates in an array and put it the js array and you see the magic. You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CxNNh/1/

Comment: Yes I get those from the db. 
Am I supposed to include the code as it is or wrap it in a function ? Thanks for your help