# How to disable selected days?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have booking form to reservastion hotels so I want to disabled selected days how can I do that ? I mean if I select `20` from first datepicker so `20` must be unselectable in second datepicker

```js
function datePicker() {
  var dateFormat = "DD/MM/YY",
    from = $("#checkin,.checkin").datepicker({
      //numberOfMonths: 2,
      firstDay: 1,
      minDate: 0,
      ignoreReadonly: true,
      showButtonPanel: true,
      closeText: 'Temizle',
      onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        if ($(window.event.srcElement).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close')) {
          document.getElementById(this.id).value = '';
          //$('.checkin,#checkin,#checkout,.checkout').val('');
        }
      },
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        window.setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
          $(this).parents(".book-holiday").find("#checkout,.checkout").focus();
        }, this), 10);

        var date2 = $('#checkin,.checkin').datepicker('getDate');
        date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
        $('#checkout,.checkout').datepicker('setDate', date2);
        //sets minDate to dt1 date + 1
        $('#checkout,.checkout').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
      },
      isTo1: true,
      beforeShow: function(input, inst) {

        $(this).datepicker("widget").addClass("main-datepicker");
        // controlDatepicker(".checkin,#checkin");
        /*setTimeout(function() {
            inst.dpDiv.css({
                top: $(".datepicker").offset().top + 35,
                left: $(".datepicker").offset().left
            });
        }, 0);*/
      }
    });
  $("#checkout,.checkout").datepicker({
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: 0,
    ignoreReadonly: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    closeText: 'Temizle',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
      if ($(window.event.srcElement).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close')) {
        document.getElementById(this.id).value = '';
        //$('.checkin,#checkin,#checkout,.checkout').val('');
      }
      var dt1 = $('#checkin.checkin').datepicker('getDate');
      console.log(dt1);
      var dt2 = $('#checkout,.checkout').datepicker('getDate');
      if (dt2 <= dt1) {
        var minDate = $('#checkin,.checkin').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
        $('#checkin,.checkout').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
      }
    },
    ignoreReadonly: true,
    isTo1: true,
    onSelect: function() {
      //$(this).parents(".book-holiday").find(".popover-wrapper").addClass("open");
    },
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
      /* $(this).datepicker("widget").addClass("main-datepicker");
       controlDatepicker(".checkin,#checkin");
       setTimeout(function() {
           inst.dpDiv.css({
               top: $(".datepicker").offset().top + 35,
               left: $(".datepicker").offset().left
           });
       }, 0);*/
    }

  });

}


datePicker();
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> From : <input type="text" class="checkin"> To: <input type="text" class="checkout">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: var specialDays = {'08/01/2012': 'booked', '08/02/2012': 'enquiry'};
$('#date').datepicker({beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      date = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
      var special = specialDays[date] || '';
      return [special == '', special];
}});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$("#dt1").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
            minDate: 0,
            onSelect: function (date) {
                var date2 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
                date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
                $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', date2);
                //sets minDate to dt1 date + 1
                $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
            }
        });
        $('#dt2').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
            onClose: function () {
                var dt1 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
                console.log(dt1);
                var dt2 = $('#dt2').datepicker('getDate');
                if (dt2 <= dt1) {
                    var minDate = $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                    $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
                }
            }
        });
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/PPSh3/3/)

Comment: Hi, I tried your code is work but I guess it have a littler bug.when I select first day it select automatically second day.I edited my post.

Comment: It's not a bug, its the functionality implemented in the fiddle and you can remove this by commenting some lines. Check the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/PPSh3/2768/

Comment: but then I can selected past days again ? which code shoul I remove ?

Comment: great Mayank thanks last question I have to learn it is a just question: can I set class first and last selected on datepicker ?

Comment: I think so, just google it and you will get so many help links

Comment: I don't know 'keyword' how can I search on google, thanks again it works very well

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to store date and compare them when action is triggered? In that case you will not trigger any action when condition is not fulfilled.

Or you could use something iike that:
[Jquery UI datepicker. Disable array of Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates)

Comment: I only need to selected days I guess there is no reason to use arrays