# Wordpress Contact Form 7 - specific dates (datepicker)

Tags: wordpress, forms, date, contacts

So I have a form, written using Contact Form 7 plugin, and
I want to include a datepicker there (only date, without time).
By default, the only things I can change are:
minDate(); maxDate(); step();

In my form, I want to have something available for booking
but it will be only tuesdays, fridays and saturdays.

Is there ANY way to restrict Contact Form 7 Datepicker to
highlight only these days in the calendar (and allow user to click and choose them)?

Comment: did you found an answer? I am looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't check it, but after some research I think the best way is to:

1) write your own PHP form, don't use Contact Form 7
2) include JQuery datepicker in it: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
3) add one of the solutions from here: [Jquery UI datepicker. Disable array of Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates)