# If any disabled dates between start date and end date, alert user about booking not possible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a booking page. eg, The booking start on `2018-01-10` and end on `2018-01-20`.

If some date `2018-01-15` and `2018-01-16` are disabled so how can we inform user "there is some disabled dates in between `2018-01-10` and `2018-01-20` so bookings not possible".

or

Not clickable end date.

```
$("#dateFrom").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd.mm.y",
                monthNames: ['Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'August', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Dezember'],
                monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez"],
                dayNamesMin: ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"],
                minDate: 0,
                beforeShowDay: ["2018-01-15","2018-01-16"],
});
```

Comment: What isn't working?   What did you try and how did it fail?    As is, I don't think anyone could actually answer other than to say, write some code that checks it and take appropriate action.

Comment: This sounds a bit complicated. Just grey out the dates where no booking is possible. And make something like `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze, I updated my question

Comment: @LawfulEvil I updated my question. I hope now it is easy to understand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery UI datepicker. Disable array of Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates)