# How to Disable jQuery Datepicker from mysql value/content

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm currently doing a Hotel Reservation website and I'm trying to learn how to disable jQuery DatePickers depending on the values from database.

For example, the dates *March 1* up to *March 5* are inserted into the **Database A** tables `checkin` and `checkout` rows.

So now `checkin` has **March 1** value and `checkout` has **March 5**.

Let's say I have two jQuery datepicker, one for *checkin* and one for *checkout*. How do I disable the days **March 1** and **March 5** in them taken from the value inside the database?

Here's my current **script** for the datepicker:

```
$(function () {

$("#checkin").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "M-dd-yy",
    minDate: 0,
    onClose: function () {


        var date2 = $('#checkin').datepicker('getDate');
        date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
        $('#checkout').datepicker('setDate', date2);
        $('#checkout ').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
         datepicked();

      $('#checkout').datepicker('option');



}
});
$('#checkout').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "M-dd-yy",
    minDate: 0,

    onSelect: function () {
        var dt1 = $('#checkin ').datepicker('getDate');
        var dt2 = $('#checkout').datepicker('getDate');
        datepicked();
        //check to prevent a user from entering a date below date of dt1

    if (dt2 <= dt1) {
            var minDate = $('#checkout ').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
            $('#checkout').datepicker('setDate', minDate);


           $('#checkin').datepicker('option');



    }


    }

});


var datepicked = function() {
var checkin = $('#checkin');
var checkout = $('#checkout');
var nights = $('#nights');

    var fromDate = checkin.datepicker('getDate');

    var toDate = checkout.datepicker('getDate');

    if (toDate && fromDate) {

        var oneDay = 1000*60*60*24; 
        var difference = Math.ceil((toDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime()) / oneDay); 
        nights.val(difference);
        } 
};
 });  
$(function () { 
$("#date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    minDate: 0,
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: new Date() 
});
   });
```

Thank you very much in advanced.

Comment: Where's your [mcve]? What have you tried?

Comment: @j08691 I've added my *working* datepicker script.

Comment: @JoshuaC, you provided no server side code in PHP !

Answer (score 0):

If you try to set initial value's for this input's just use `setDate` after datepicker initializtion.
In PHP set value attribute for input:

```
<input id="checkin" value="<?= date('M-dd-yy', $valueFromDbCheckin) ?>">
```

And just call `setDate`:

```
$( "#checkin" ).datepicker( "setDate", $('checkin').val() );
```

If you try to disable some date's in datepicker's then you probably could try this solution:
[Disable array of date's Jquery DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates)