# Can the jQuery UI Datepicker be made to disable Friday and Saturday (and allow only choose after 3 days)?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Can the jQuery UI Datepicker be made to allow user to choose date only after three days from today and (not calculate the weekend days) .
Weekend Day is : Friday and Saturday.
For example: if today is Thursday the user must allow choose date from Wednesday
and if today is Sunday user can choose date from Thursday.

Comment: http://www.spiceforms.com/blog/how-to-disable-dates-in-jquery-datepicker-a-short-guide/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates

Comment: how to disable dynamic days, all days before 3 days from today??