# Disable array of dates with Jquery datepicker Not Working - dates will not disable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have an array of dates pulled from a database that I am trying to disable on the datepicker.  The array below is the results from my database.  Using [Jquery UI datepicker. Disable array of Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates) as guidance, I tried to disable the dates from my array.  My page is connected to 
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` and my own .js file.

From my HTML page:
`<input id="resDate">`

From my JavaScript file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
blackoutDates(); 
});
function blackoutDates() {
var unavailableDates = ["10/27/2018", "11/8/2018", "4/25/2018"]
$(function () {
        $("#resDate").datepicker({
            todayHighlight: true,
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', date);
                return [unavailableDates.indexOf(string) == -1]
            }
        });
    });
}
```

On [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Liz4210/aox5who2/7/) the result is that the dates are completely unaffected (i.e. none are disabled).  On my page, I received the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatDate' of undefined".
Since that function did not work, I also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
blackoutDates(); 
});
function blackoutDates() {
var unavailableDates = ["10/27/2018", "11/8/2018", "4/25/2018"]
$(function () {
        $("#resDate").datepicker({
            todayHighlight: true,
            beforeShowDay: function unavailable(date) {
                dmy = date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + 
date.getFullYear();
                if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
                    return [true, "","Available"];
                } else {
                    return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This did not disable any dates on both my page and [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Liz4210/ukvrrvnf/6/).  When I step through it while debugging with Chrome, the loop breaks after May 5,2018.  Maybe it is having issues because it did not reach all of my array dates?

I have really confused myself.  All advice is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution:

`jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', date)` return `mm/dd/yyyy`, but the element of `var unavailableDates` is like `"4/25/2018"`.

Your second solution:

your string format is different with `var unavailableDates`. one is `mm/dd/yyyy`, the other one is `dd/mm/yyyy`.

After fixed that, your codes should work.

Perhaps you already knew, beforeShowDay need to return one array:

**As API defines:**

> A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array
>   with:
>
> ```
> [0]: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable
> [1]: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default presentation
> [2]: an optional popup tooltip for this date
> ```

And another point is each element of `var unavailableDates` is string.
but the parameter of `beforeShowDay` is one date object, I prefer to predefining each element of `var unavailableDates` with `new Date()`

**Then below is my solution**

1. change each element of `var unavailableDates` to Date object. like `new Date(2018, 09, 27)`
2. get [`new Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from `var unavailableDates`, then just simple check by `.has()` whether `dateStr` existes in that `set()`. (Also you can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to check whether the date is unselectable). If true, return `[false, 'your css class', 'your tooltip'],
   if false, return [true,'',null]

**PS:** use `Set()`, we can avoid loop the array again and again, it will improve the efficiency a lot.

3. add one CSS class which is in `var unavailableDates`, you can customize the CSS=`.disable-day` by yourself.

Update: Added sample codes for .Net.

Below is the working sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   blackoutDates(); 
});
function blackoutDates() {
    //assuming <%=DateTimeText%> is one string like mm-dd-yyyy;mm-dd-yyyy
    var unavailableAspxDatesString = '10-27-2018;11-08-2018;04-25-2018'   //= '<%=DateTimeText%>'
    let unavailableDateSet = new Set(unavailableAspxDatesString.split(';'))
    /*var unavailableDates = [new Date(2018, 09, 27), new Date(2018, 10, 08), new Date(2018, 03, 25)]
    let unavailableDateSet = new Set(unavailableDates.map(function(item){
      return jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', item)
    }))*/
  $(function () {
      $("#resDate").datepicker({
          todayHighlight: true,
          beforeShowDay: function (calDate) {
              return unavailableDateSet.has(jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', calDate)) ? [false, 'disable-day', 'no available day!!!'] : [true, '','']
              /*
              return unavailableDates.filter(function(item){
                return item.getTime()==calDate.getTime()}).length > 0 ? [false, 'disable-day',                     'no available day!!!'] : [true, '','']*/
              
          }
      });
  });
}
```

```css
.disable-day{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="resDate">
```

Comment: Thank you but that still doesn't disable them.  How do I change the elements pulled from C# into date objects? Also why does 1 month get added to those dates during the mapping?

Comment: @LizzyTimm added sample codes for .Net. Then you said 'still doesn't disable them'? but the snippet in my answer seems working fine, 4/25/2018 is not selectable. may you provide more details? thanks.

Comment: I agree, it does work when just running the snippet.  I think it is because this page that I'm updating was generated by WordPress so there are 30+ js files attached (no exaggeration).  There must be something in one of those scripts that is not allowing days to be disabled.  I was hoping I could get by without having to look through each file but I will start doing that.  Thank you!