# disable jquery datepicker 7 days before and after from current date

Tags: jquery

DOJ:

Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var selector = function (dateStr) {
    var d1 = $('.fromdate').datepicker('getDate');
    var d2 = $('.todate').datepicker('getDate');
    var diff = 0;
    if (d1 && d2)
    {
        diff = Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000); // ms per day
    }
    $('.calculated').val(diff);
} 


$(".fromdate").datepicker({
    maxDate: "+3",
    minDate: "+3"
    //minDate: new Date(2012, 7 - 1, 8),
    //maxDate: new Date(2012, 7 - 1, 28)
});

$('.todate').datepicker({
    //setDate: new Date('01/01/1970'),
    minDate: new Date(2012, 7 - 1, 9),
    maxDate: new Date(2012, 7 - 1, 28)
});



  $('.fromdate,.todate').change(selector)


});
```

i want to show dates only 7 days before and 7 days after from **current date**, rest of calender remain disabled. Am also calculating days with these datepicker

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery UI datepicker. Disable array of Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates)

Comment: no i want to disable remaining calendar and show dates only 7 days before and after from current date

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$(".fromdate").datepicker({
    maxDate: "+7",
    minDate: "-7"
});
```