# Disable dates using jQuery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I understand that we can disable certain dates ([Jquery UI datepicker. Disable array of Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates)) by manually specifying each date in array however this seems like a messy solution to a problem.

Is there a simpler method of just providing a start and end date of a period in which dates should be disabled? i.e. `07/07/2020` to `07/08/2020` rather than specifying each date between these?