# disabling particular date in input box using jquery in php not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, date

i have a php website, there is a form which user can submit, i want to disable few dates if they are already present in database, so i did like below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="niy" name="idate" value=""/>

 <?php
    $queryusersz = "SELECT * FROM invoice";
    $dbz = mysqli_query($con, $queryusersz);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbz)) {
   $names[] = $row['idate'];      
    ?>
    
    <script>
    var array = <?php $names ?>;

$('#niy').datepicker({
    language:'TR',
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
    </script>
  <?php }?>
```

however the input box doesnt show date and neither i get any errors in console, can anyone please help me with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try:  var array = <?php echo json_encode($names); ?>;

Comment: @KHIMAJIVALUKIYA my issue is the calander is not at all coming while clicking that input box

Comment: Have you added jQuery UI JS Library? you need to add jQuery UI Library for DatePicker, Not only JQuery Library

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3q0zkp2c/

Comment: @KHIMAJIVALUKIYA i added jquery cdn and datepicker cdn, i get console error datepicker is not a function

Comment: I have added JQuery and jQuery UI versions in fille, please check.  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js    https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css

Comment: Can you please create Snidest of code which you are executing?

Comment: @KHIMAJIVALUKIYA https://jsfiddle.net/Lgr6semz/ this is my code

Comment: Check this, did by Refrence of your code: https://jsfiddle.net/wkrq6fhj/

Comment: Just Changed: var array = '<?php echo json_encode($names); ?>';

Comment: @KHIMAJIVALUKIYA thanks its working fine now, but the date is coming in black and white, how do i get it like u did , i mean in color

Comment: You need to add CSS for it: <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For jQuery DatePicker, You need to add jQuery UI JS and CSS.

There are two things you need to follow:

1. You can not directly write `var array = <?php $names ?>;` in JS as It will give error, You need to do JSON Encode or You need to add it in quote.

For Exmaple: `var array = <?php echo json_encode($names); ?>` or `var array = '<?php echo implode(",",$names); ?>'`

2. One more thing you missed in code is You didn't added echo for PHP variable which you are using in JS.

For Example: Right now your code is `var array = <?php $names ?>;`, It is without echo so that `$name` value will not store in JS variable until you echo it.

For more reference see below code:

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <input id="niy" name="idate" value=""/>

    <?php
        $queryusersz = "SELECT * FROM invoice";
        $dbz = mysqli_query($con, $queryusersz);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbz)) {
        $names[] = $row['idate'];      
        ?>
        
        <script>
        var array = '<?php echo implode(",",$names) ?>';

            $('#niy').datepicker({
                language:'TR',
                beforeShowDay: function(date){
                    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                    return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
                }
            });
        </script>
    <?php }?>
```

Comment: i added bro the css as you said, but its not working, its coming in black and white

Comment: Can you Please show me how CSS are you loading?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

Comment: Why Bootstrap Datepicker UI Js is there?

Comment: i removed it now the color came but there is an issues, when i echo this <?php echo json_encode($names); ?> , i get values like this ["2021-12-16"] ["2021-12-16","2020-12-15"]

Comment: I changed it in Answer: Use:  var array = '<?php echo implode(",",$names) ?>';

Comment: now its coming like 2021-12-16 2021-12-16,2020-12-15, the first date is shown separate and then array is shown, so only first date is being disabled

Comment: As per your code, It will check selected date in this whole string and Disable it, It does not matter it's first, Second, Or last.

Comment: For more Refrence of your requirement, Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates/15400806

Comment: Code–only answers aren't that helpful. A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.