# disable date range in Joomla calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla1.7

I want to disable a date range in joomla calendar. Only the remaining days can be select. I have no idea how to do it. Plz help.

e.g. If I say 2012-2-20 to 2012-3-20 then only days in this range can be select all other has to be disable(or can not select).

**Joomla Calendar Doc**
http://docs.joomla.org/API16:JHtml/calendar

Comment: This ain't very easy at all, but [see this](http://technologymisc.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/joomla-hide-past-days-from-calendar-control/) for a bit of related code.

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically? You'll probably be better off writing something custom for this.

Comment: Ok, where exactly do you want to accomplish this? Is this in a custom component or extension? On the front end or in the admin back end?

Comment: @BrentFriar In a custom component @ the backend.

Comment: This might be worth checking out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890418/datepicker-for-web-page-that-can-allow-only-specific-dates-to-be-clicked

Answer (score 1):

Set `minDate` and `maxDate` for your date limit, i.e.

```
$("#start_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    minDate: newmindate ,
    maxDate: newmaxdate 
});
```

Set variable `newmindate` and `newmaxdate`.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is add a little snippet of code in Javascript where any time you have an event on blur on that input you retrieve the value, check if it is `>  2012-2-10 && < 2012-3-10`, and
if not clear the value of that input.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with several Joomla sites that I administer. I was already using jQuery, so I decided to go with [JQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max) which has an easy-to-use min/max date feature. If you're already using these libraries, or if you're willing to 1) add them and 2) potentially mess up your design unity, I would recommend it.

Comment: Yes I tried spending lot of time with Joomla calender but failed. So I had to use JQuery UI Datepicker to do it but still thinking and hoping to do the same thing using joomla calender.

Comment: @Sara let me know if you do... I too would like a native solution on my Joomla sites.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <input name="StartDate" id="StartDate" type="text" readOnly="readonly" data-val-required="The From field is required." data-val="true" jQuery15106987620498322786="53"/>
    <input name="EndDate" id="EndDate" type="text" readOnly="readonly" data-val-required="The To field is required." data-val="true" jQuery15106987620498322786="54"/>
</div>

$(function () {
    var dates = $("#StartDate, #EndDate").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate:0,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            var option = this.id == "StartDate" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                    instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                        selectedDate, instance.settings);
            dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

3 years after your question and the calendar field in Joomla still can't do this. However, you can set a minimum year and a maximum year (but not a minimum month and a maximum month) by just editing the file `media/system/js/calendar.js` and changing the values of `this.minYear` and `this.maxYear` to the values of your choice.