# Disable specific days of the week on jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the jQuery UI Datepicker be made to disable Saturdays and Sundays (and holidays)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holid)

I would like to disable certain days like every monday or every tuesday or every monday, thursday friday, etc. on a jQuery UI datepicker.

I tried to play with beforeShowDay, but that requires a specific date.  I just want to disable an entire day of the week.

Update: Thanks for the suggested solutions, but they all work for specific dates.  What if I wanted to disable every single Monday and Tuesday for the entire year.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can ue the [`beforeShowDate` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) of the datepicker combined with [`Date.getDay()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) to do what you want, like this:

```
​$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 1 && day != 2)];
    }
})​​​​​;​
```

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Fy9/), this just takes the date, checks if it's a Monday (1) or Tuesday (2) and returns false for the first array entry if that's the case.

Comment: How can this be modified and be used with checkboxes? For example, user will have an option of 7 checkboxes - one for each day of the week with values for the according days, and if user checks off just Monday, and then clicks on datepicker field, to show mondays only, and if they select/add/check more, then more days will be enabled in datepicker?

Comment: @Xander look at this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmQrPY

Comment: @SebastiánRojas Thank you :) Will come in handy again

Comment: `getUTCDay` should be used for localization purposes. In some parts of the world, Monday is the start of the week.

Comment: this doesnt work in mine it gives a date picker but i can pick anydate