# How to validate datepicker to forbid/reject certain dates?

Tags: jquery, validation, datepicker

I have this Calendar Control I am using. A user can select any date from the calendar. I need to validate the dates like Saturday and Sundays and 1/1 and 1/25. If they select these days I need to show them a Popup message if it's not a valid date.

Comment: "how to validate" is a really poor question title. Please improve it.

Comment: Changed title to the more specific _"How to validate datepicker to forbid/reject certain dates?"_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("input[id^='Date-<%=Model.ID%>']").change(function() {
    var date = new Date($(this).val()).getDay();
    if(date == 0 || date == 6) {
        alert('weekend');
    }
});
```

This is set up with a `change` event. Your event may be different.

It get's the value of the input: `$(this).val()`

Creates a new `Date` object from it: `new Date($(this).val())`

Then gets the day number: `.getDay()` which returns a value from 0 to 6 with 0 being Sunday and 6 being Saturday.

Then you just test for 0 or 6.

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/UwcLf/

---

**EDIT:** Courtesy of **Nick Craver**, you can disable specific days if you have no need to run alternate code for weekend selections.

From Nick's linked answer: [Disable specific days of the week on jQuery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968414/#2973696)

```
$("input[id^='Date-<%=Model.ID%>']").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 0 && day != 6)];
    }
})​​​​​;​
```

**Updated Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/UwcLf/1/

**Added array for disabled days:** http://jsfiddle.net/UwcLf/3/

Comment: +1 - I would combine this with disabling them in the datepicker itself as well, feel free to include this code in your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968414/#2973696

Comment: @Nick - Thanks, I'll include your code. +1 on your linked answer. :o)

Comment: Thanks Nick, but how to validate 1/1 and 1/25 each year?

Comment: @Nick - Thanks. I was a little slow on the uptake on that one! Posted a similar version in my answer, then saw that you already had one. :o)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the JQUery UI DatePicker, it has an onSelect event, you could use this to validate the selected date.

I don't know your back-end, or if you're using one, but you could always send the selected date to your server via an Ajax call and determine if it's valid or not.

Have a look at [Custom Validators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) if you're using ASP.Net.