# jQuery/JavaScript: Is it a date? (Validate whether is a date)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, date, datepicker

I have datepicker, but I could not find a way to validate if the user's entry is a date or not AND if it follows the required format (**format: yyyy-mm-dd**)

This is my datepicker:

```
$("input[name='date']").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, numberOfMonths: 3, showButtonPanel: true});
```

I looked on this solution, "[How to validate datepicker to forbid/reject certain dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990610/how-to-validate)". It looks simple enough, but it only checks whether it's a weekend. It does not checks it the user entered a date, a random number or a typo (1231....30-30-2011...30/30/2011...212-565-565...etc.).

Please fiddle with my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MDa4A/

**Additional info (11-10-2011):**
(Try these jsFiddles and type 0-0-0 or 0/0/0)

I used your answers to come up with a solution. It works when I use the format **"yy-mm-dd"**: http://jsfiddle.net/LyEvQ/

BUT it is totally useless when I use a different format **(Ej.: "mm/dd/yy")**: http://jsfiddle.net/LyEvQ/1/

I need both to work. Can you please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880615/isdate-in-jquery

Comment: Please update my fiddle with your answer: [http://jsfiddle.net/MDa4A/](http://jsfiddle.net/MDa4A/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("customDateValidator",
    function(value, element) {
        try { jQuery.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yyyy", value); return true; }
        catch(e) { 
            return false;
        }
    },
    "Please enter a valid date"
);

$("input[name='date']").rules("add", { customDateValidator:true });
```

Comment: can you please give me a jsFiddle example? -I tried your answer and could not make it work by myself =(

Comment: If you're using datepicker anyway (you probably are), this seems like a better validator than just simply using `Date.parse`

Comment: If some get error " Missing number at position 10" or parse not working then try `"mm/dd/yy"` instead of "mm/dd/yyyy"

Comment: I've never seen the jQuery validator put to use. Very cool. Upvote for you. Thanks

Comment: I think it is not a good idea to validate dates by handling the exceptions. @James Hill has provided a better solution for that.

Comment: datepicker that is setup on an input element still allows the entering in of an invalid date - so some kind of a check for valid dates are needed Unfortunately Date.parse is not it. Date.parse will accept integers like 1111 as a valid date.

Answer (score 44):

```
if (Date.parse("some string")) {
   //Valid date
} else {
  //Not a valid date
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp

Comment: This is not correct, as it returns number instead of NaN for e.g. 2014-11-31 which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 11):

Use the [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method to check if a date is valid:

```
var timestamp = Date.parse($("input[name='date']").val()) 

if (isNaN(timestamp) == false) { 
    var d = new Date(timestamp); 
}
```

Comment: `Date.parse` has inconsistent implementations across browsers, and I wouldn't use it as a validator. For example, integers +-20,000 or so are valid Dates (`Date.parse("200000")`), but I wouldn't want to accept that as input.

Comment: and it neither validates if the date is valid, only checks that day is between 1 and 31, month between 1 and 12, etc.
`Date.parse('2000-11-31') == Date.parse('2000-12-01')`

Comment: I would use: if(isNaN(Date.parse($("input[name='date']").val()){isNotDate}, writing less code should be the overall goal, atleast it is for me.

Comment: @TGarrett, don't you think that readable, maintainable code should be the goal?

Comment: @jameshill, yes'sir, readability is a huge concern when it comes to all code and having the developer after you who will make changes to your code, should be super easy for them to pick up, no matter what coding level the person may be at. What I did, was cleaned up the pieces that seemed redundant to me, such as having an equal operator for a bolean when you can simply remove that and add in any logic operator in there such as "!", for most who have been programming a for some time(1-2years), will be able to pick-up on it very fast. Different coding styles are another discussion that happens:

Comment: Date.parse("this is a BAD date 2029")  returns a VALID date.  The year at the end of the strings fools the parser.

Comment: Date.parse(myDateVariable) allows stuff like 1111 which is clearly not a date. It disallows 31/31/2023 which is good.