# Disable days in jQuery Datepicker depend on other properties in model MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to disable specific days of the week in `jQuery UI DatePicker` , depending on whether a value is true or false in the model submitted in @razor view .

I have a bool for each weekday . If a value is constructed so will the day be available in datepickern but if false, then the day will be disabled.

I looked around on different sides here but none of these options worked for me .
Here is my code :

```
$('#txtStartDate').datepicker({
    defaultDate: '+1w',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    showAnim: 'slide',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showWeek: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: new Date(hidStartDate),
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();

        if (day == 1 && $('#hidMonday').val() == "True") {
            return day;
        }

        if (day == 2 && $('#hidTuesday').val() == "True") {
            return day;
        }

        if (day == 3 && $('#hidWednesday').val() == "True") {
            return day;
        }

        if (day == 4 && $('#hidThursday').val() == "True") {
            return day;
        }

        if (day == 5 && $('#hidFriday').val() == "True") {
            return day;
        }
    },
});

$('#txtStartDate').css('clip', 'auto');
```

Once it has gone through about 5-6 days in the calendar , I get the following error in the console

> " Jquery - ui.js : 9742 uncaught TypeError : Can not read property '0'
>   of undefined "

That said , I have looked around on the solution proposed here , but it may not work. This solution is based on the following proposal:

[Disable specific days of the week on jQuery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968414/disable-specific-days-of-the-week-on-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Fy9/1136/)

```
if (day == 1 && $('#hidMonday').val() == "True") {
            return day;
        }

        if (day == 2 && $('#hidTuesday').val() == "True") {
            return day;
        }
```

> The error is coming when no day object is returned(when it is not
>   getting into any of the if conditions). You can not simply not return
>   anything   Better return false  if any of the conditions is not met

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When i tried to return false when no condistion is met it disables all days even if some days should be enabled?

Comment: u need to return true also. When you condition is met

Answer (score 1):

Acutally `beforeShowday` should return an array. That's what its document says

```
beforeShowDay 

Type: Function( Date date )
Default: null
A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:
[0]: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable
[1]: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default presentation
[2]: an optional popup tooltip for this date
```

*By default you can send null , otherwise return an `array[flag,"",""] where flag is false for disabling`