# How to disable current week in jquery datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to solve this problem. Still I have done this,

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate:1 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

If you run this code you can see the calendar.

I want to disable the full current week. The available dates will start from next week.
As, Example, today is `18.07.2016`. So, if someone want to use this calendar then this full week become inactive. Next available date will start from `24.07.2016`.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: By *current week* you mean calendar week right? Not just 7 days

Comment: Yes. only the calendar week. Sunday to Saturday.

Comment: Have a look at this post, might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968414/disable-specific-days-of-the-week-on-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: Yes. I have seen. But this post is for only want to disable specific week day or days of every week. But I don't want that. I want to disable only the current week. Only current Sunday to Saturday.

Comment: Read the the comment please. I have written Sunday to Saturday not Sunday n Saturday.

Answer (score 2):

First find the number of day of week. And mindate will be counted accordingly and all the dates of current week will be disabled. Please refer below code.

```
$(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var dayNo = date.getDay();
    var mindate = (7-dayNo);

    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', firstDay: 1,minDate: mindate
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the current week from Sunday to Saturday, you just need to set the `firstDay` as 0 (for Sunday) and use `beforeShowDay` which is used to take date as a parameter and return an array. For reference read [Datepicker Option - beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay)

Please check the snippet to enable all other dates in past and future both except disabling the current week dates.

> Disable from **Sunday to Saturday**, use the below snippet

```js
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        firstDay: 0,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var sunday = new Date();
            sunday.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            
            sunday.setDate(sunday.getDate() - (sunday.getDay() || 0));
            var saturday = new Date(sunday.getTime());
            
            saturday.setDate(sunday.getDate() + 6);
            
            if (date >= sunday && date <= saturday) {
              return [false, ''];
            }
            else {
              return [true, ''];
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

> And, also possibility to disable the whole week starting from **Monday
>   to Sunday**

```js
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        firstDay: 1,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
           var monday = new Date();
           monday.setHours(0,0,0,0);

           monday.setDate(monday.getDate() + 1 - (monday.getDay() || 7));
           var sunday = new Date(monday);
           sunday.setDate(monday.getDate() + 6);

           if (date >= monday && date <= sunday) {
              return [false, ''];
           } else {
               return [true, ''];
          }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Answer (score 0):

Its A Simple Way TO Disable a Perticular Week

```
<script>
 $(function(){
$('.bet_end').datepicker({              //ere .bet_end Is A Datepicker Class Name
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]   //Here Type Only Column Number To Disable Week 
     });
}); 
</script>
```

[Click here To See Image (Sunday And Saturdat All Week Are Disable)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0tJz.png)