# Setting Delivery Date picker in Shopify for specific items only

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I'm trying to get the delivery date picker in Shopify to only be available for specific items please. Here's the code I currently have..

```js
{{ '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js' | script_tag }}

<div class="pickadate">
  <p>
    <label for="date">Pick a pick up date:</label>
    <input id="date" type="text" name="attributes[date]" value="{{ cart.attributes.date }}" />
    <span style="display:block" class="instructions"> <strong>Please note, cleanses need to be picked up between 9am and 10am from:</strong> <br /><br /><strong>The Juice Parlor</strong><br />5658 Cahuenga Blvd,<br />North Hollywood, CA 91601.</span>
  </p>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#date").datepicker( { 
    
    minDate: +2, 
    maxDate: '+2M',
    beforeShowDay: jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends
  } );
  
});
</script>

{% comment %}
  To remove days of the week that aren't Saturday and Sunday, use this:
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968414/disable-specific-days-of-the-week-on-jquery-ui-datepicker
{% endcomment %}

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery('input[name="checkout"], input[name="goto_pp"], input[name="goto_gc"]').click(function() {
            if (jQuery('#date').val() == '') {
                alert("You must pick a pick up date.");
                return false;
            } else {
                jQuery(this).submit();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I only want to have the code require and even show the delivery date option if the item in the cart is for "Cleanse" only.

And if there are 2 items in the cart.. like a cleanse and a t-shirt... I only want the date picker to be available for the "Cleanse" please.

Comment: "Cleanse" is it product title? Can you also include a HTML how you rendering line items in your shopping cart

Comment: Sure here is the link to the cart: https://the-juice-parlor.myshopify.com/cart

Comment: There is a basic t-shirt item and a cleanse item on the site for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work for you. This code is checking if in your cart you have `Cleanse` item, then it's showing date picked and making this datepicker as required

```
{% assign productTitleStr =  cart.items | map: 'title'| uniq | join: ', ' %}
{% if productTitleStr contains 'Cleanse' %}
    <link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <div class="pickadate">
        <p>
            <label for="date">Pick a pick up date:</label>
            <input id="date" type="text" name="attributes[date]" value="" required/>
            <span style="display:block" class="instructions"> <strong>Please note, cleanses need to be picked up between 9am and 10am from:</strong> <br /><br /><strong>The Juice Parlor</strong><br />5658 Cahuenga Blvd,<br />North Hollywood, CA 91601.</span>
        </p>
    </div>

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#date").datepicker( {
                minDate: +2, 
                maxDate: '+2M',
                beforeShowDay: jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends
            });
            jQuery('input[name="checkout"], input[name="goto_pp"], input[name="goto_gc"]').click(function() {
                if (jQuery('#date').val() == '') {
                    alert("You must pick a pick up date.");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    jQuery(this).submit();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Amazing! Worked! Thank you!