# Jquery UI datepicker to allow dynamic specific days of week only

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to disable certain days in a jQuery UI datepicker based on the days entered in one of the input boxes by the user.

If i enter **MWF** it should only allow me to only select the dates which falls on either "**M**"onday , "**W**"ednesday ot "**F**"riday

I am able to dynamically construct the return value sting which needs to be set in the return statement.

```
 for (var j=0; j < arr.length; j++)
      mystr = mystr + "day != " + arr[j] + " && ";

      mystr = mystr.substring(0, mystr.length - 3);
```

This gives me the following text in mystr variable:

```
day != 3 && day != 4 && day != 6
```

which needs to passed on to the return statement like :

```
​$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(mystr)];
    }
})​​​​​;​
```

This is not working....

I am able to disable the days i want if i explicitly set it in return statement. But i need to dynamically restrict days selection in the datepicker based on days entered in the text box. I can get the days dynamically and also have the dynamic return statement ready. Its not working.

FULL CODE :

```
            var batchdays = ['M', 'T', 'W', 'H', 'F', 'S'];
            var batchcode= "MWF";
            var batchdaysarray = batchcode.replace(/\d+/g, '').split('');
            var arr = [];
            var arrayLength = batchdaysarray.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                    if ($.inArray(batchdaysarray[i], batchdays) != -1) {
                        arr.push($.inArray(batchdaysarray[i], batchdays)+1);
                    }
            }

            var mystr = '';

            for (var j=0; j < arr.length; j++)
                mystr = mystr + "day != " + arr[j] + " && ";

            mystr = mystr.substring(0, mystr.length - 3);

            alert(mystr);
            console.log(mystr);

            $('#actual_start_dt').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
                nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
                beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                    var day = date.getDay();
                    return [(mystr)];
                }
            });
```

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable specific days of the week on jQuery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968414/disable-specific-days-of-the-week-on-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably think that you have already resolved this issue on your own. The problem with the code you have provided is,

```
return [(mystr)];
```

According to the jquery-ui documentation [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) is,

> A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array
>   with:
>
> 1. true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable
> 2. a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default
>      presentation
> 3. an optional popup tooltip for this date

In your example, you are however passing string,

```
 for (var j=0; j < arr.length; j++)
    mystr = mystr + "day != " + arr[j] + " && ";

 mystr = mystr.substring(0, mystr.length - 3);
```

which doesn't transpose as statement when used in `return [(mystr)];`

Instead you can use following,

```
 beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var day = date.getDay();
      return [($.inArray(day, arr) != -1)];
  }
```

Please see this JSFiddle Demo[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/5676/).

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes... I got it...  but this only allows me to select Wednesdays and Fridays even if i am trying to allow "MWF" i.e. Monday too should be allowed... I tried with 4 days like MWFS in this case Wed Fri and Sat are enabled but "Monday" is disabled.... Cant figure out why :-(

Comment: Eureka ..... :-)

beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var day = date.getDay();
      return [($.inArray(day, arr) !== -1)];
      }


This was the lifesaver :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867599/jquery-inarray-how-to-use-it-right

Comment: Glad it worked out for you... I have updated the answer with the suggestion you have mention. Thanks.