# Is it possible to exclude a day-of week within selected range with datepicker (Jquery UI)

Tags: jquery

How can I exclude 'Wednesday'(for example) from a range of dates. I have no trouble setting start / end days, but need to disable days when club is closed.

Comment: i dont know how your code looks, but if you can put if statement somewhere you could divide day buy number for example wednesday should be divided buy 3 and if it is equle to 1 than disable that day ... show some code you have might have better idea

Comment: Use the answer found in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968414/disable-specific-days-of-the-week-on-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the jQuery UI Datepicker be made to disable Saturdays and Sundays (and holidays)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holid)