# Date Picker not working on the page in Shopify

Tags: html, shopify, jquery-ui-datepicker, liquid

I have been working on my form, and I have this date picker to be there in my form. Since I have tried enough thing from the web, but somehow it is failing or I must say not working at all. I have followed this [JQuery UI Date Picker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

This is my code, and I'm pretty much sure that I've been implementing it correctly but still it doesn't work.

**theme.liquid**

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 9]> <html class="ie9 no-js" lang="{{ shop.locale }}"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="{{ shop.locale 
}}"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <!-- Date Picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

**formpage.liquid**

```
<form>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date">Date of Purchase (dd/mm/YYYY)</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder=''>
   </div>
</form>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

The **formpage.liquid** is a different page, and **theme.liquid** is actually the global html page for the shopify theme. Please help me on this. Thanks :)

**Edits**

I tried to follow the same for the delivery date addition on the cart page, thought it'd work out. [Delivery Date on Cart Page Shopify](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/cart/add-date-picker-for-delivery-dates)

Made a snippet **date-picker** and added the following code :

**date-picker.liquid**

```
{{ '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js' | script_tag }}

<input id="date" type="text" name="attributes[date]" value="" />


<script>
  jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#date").datepicker( { 
      minDate: +1, 
      maxDate: '+2M',
      beforeShowDay: jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends
    } );
  });
</script>

{% comment %}
  To remove days of the week that aren't Saturday and Sunday, use this:
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968414/disable-specific-days-of- 
  the-week-on-jquery-ui-datepicker
{% endcomment %}
```

Added the snippet in the form div :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="date">Date of Purchase (dd/mm/YYYY)</label>
  {% include 'date-picker' %}
</div>
```

But still doesn't work out for me.

Comment: Can you explain how it's not working? What happens? Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: Just the text field, nothing pops up like nothing @SamJohnson. Behaves like a normal textfield in the form.

Comment: So there is no error in the console?

Comment: A lot of themes seem to end up loading in multiple copies of jQuery, an only the last one to load will reign supreme. The effect of this jQuery rush often manifests as jQuery plugins "mysteriously disappearing". Once the page is loaded, try running `jQuery.fn.jquery` in your browser's console to see if the version loaded once the dust settles is the same as the version you're expecting to be there.

Comment: No errors in the console @SamJohnson

Comment: At `date-picker.liquid` you're calling jQuery's 1.9.2 version. At `theme.liquid`. What is happening is that jQuery is not being loaded somehow; it's loading your code BEFORE jQuery UI.