# jQuery UI Datepicker be made to disable weekends and holidays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have seen an exact question being answered, but the problem is, I have absolutely no idea where to paste the codes [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holida) for mine to work. I am really a noob when it comes to programming.

Would appreciate if someone would be so kind to enlighten me as I desperately need to get my calendar working. :(

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

```
var holidays= ["2014-7-30","2015-07-29","2013-03-16"]

$('input').datepicker({
beforeShowDay:  function(date){
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
     var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
         if (noWeekend[0]) {
        return  [$.inArray(string, holidays) == -1];
        }
        else
        return noWeekend;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer:

How to start you'll find - [here](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-ui-datepicker)

**You will need theese:** (link them in top of your page.)

> 1. jQuery Library: Datepicker requires including jQuery.
> 2. JavaScript: ui.core.js and ui.datepicker.js
> 3. CSS Theme: Create your theme with ThemeRoller

You can find great demo about basis - [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

```
<script>
 $(function() {
   /*function that makes appear datepicker + you add option to disable Weekends*/
   $(".selector").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends }) 
 });
</script>

<div id="demo">
  <p>Date: <input class="selector" type="text"></p> //input field that calls the function
</div>
```

2 things to do:

1. link jquery.js + ui.core.js and
   ui.datepicker.js + your css theme to
   your page
2. paste this code into your
   webpage.

I can suggest you to do as i did - run threw a lot of tutorials, and most important thing to do - **experiment**!