# jQuery UI DatePicker exclude weekends and holidays

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code excludes dates, assigns a custom class and a title to the date field.

```
var holidays =[ [2020,06,17,'A Holiday'],[2020,06,18,'Another Holiday'],[2020,06,19,'Some Other Holiday'] ];

function setHolidays(date) {
    for (i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {
        if (date.getFullYear() == holidays[i][0]
            && date.getMonth() == holidays[i][1] - 1
            && date.getDate() == holidays[i][2]) {
            return [false, 'holiday', holidays[i][3]];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
}

$( ".add_delivery_date").datepicker( {
    minDate: 0, 
    firstDay: 0,
    beforeShowDay: setHolidays
} );
```

I know I can exclude weekends by using

```
beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
```

but I am unsure how to add it to the existing code.

Comment: I realise you have already solved the problem, but AFAICT both the question and answer  are duplicates of other questions here on SO, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holid, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561314/jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-weekends-and-holidays ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the jQuery UI Datepicker be made to disable Saturdays and Sundays (and holidays)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holid)

Comment: This answer is very useful, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than I thought:

```
function setHolidays(date) {
    for (i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {
        if (date.getFullYear() == holidays[i][0]
            && date.getMonth() == holidays[i][1] - 1
            && date.getDate() == holidays[i][2]) {
            return [false, 'holiday', holidays[i][3]];
        }
    }

    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    return !noWeekend[0] ? noWeekend : [true];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass `noWeekends: true`.

```
$( ".add_delivery_date").datepicker( {
    noWeekends: true,
    minDate: 0, 
    firstDay: 0,
    beforeShowDay: setHolidays
} );
```